# ROT-13 transform standard input

Tags: code-golf, cryptography

## Task

Read a string of characters and produce the [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rot13) of it. All characters besides `[a-zA-Z]` should be output verbatim. Each letter in the output may be in any case you wish (you do not have to preserve it).

ROT13 is a simple substitution cipher where each letter of the alphabet is rotated by 13 places (it doesn't matter whether you do it forward or backward, since ROT13 is it's own inverse).

## Examples

```
Input
Output

Hello, world!
Uryyb, jbeyq!

Code Golf and Coding Challenges is awesome.
Pbqr Tbys naq Pbqvat Punyyratrf vf njrfbzr.

Mod abuse!1!!1
Zbq nohfr!1!!1
```

Comment: The problem shouldn't be a tag, so I removed ROT13, just an FYI

Comment: Don't you mean A-Za-z (to count both upper- and lower-case) ?

Comment: and make sure they don't use rot13 in standard library? like the PHP one

Comment: @Nakilon: (Re retag.) rot13 is not cryptography (at least not in the modern sense of the word).

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young, it belongs to this category at wikipedia. It's part of cryptography, just not the hardest one. Anyway, I'm not longer following this site. Community dissapointed me. Sorry. GL HF.

Comment: @Nakilon: That is like saying XOR (for a fixed value) is encryption. That's ludicrous. Also, sorry to hear you're leaving.

Comment: Saying *xor is not encryption* is like saying *a+b is not math*.

Comment: @Nakilon: Actually, I call that arithmetic, not mathematics. \*shrug\*

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young, I thought arithmetic is part of math ,.)

Comment: xor is encryption. rot13 is encoding, as is caesar-chiffre. (chiffre = encoding)

Comment: @Nakilon If you call arithmetic math, then you're probably also inclined to call spelling writing. I've never seen someone win a spelling bee and get called a writer for it. Just as doing fast arithmetic doesn't make you a mathematician.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: The only encryption which is provably safe, the one-time pad, is *exactly* the original message XORed with a fixed value (of the same length as the message).

Comment: Tags are used to categorize questions and help search similar questions. The [tag:cryptography] tag (from Greek kryptós, "hidden, secret"; and graphein, "writing") in particular is for encryption and decryption problems. All encryption and decryption, not only those that are secure for modern applications.

Answer (score 26):

## Bash, 23 bytes

Canonical 23-character answer:

```
tr A-Za-z N-ZA-Mn-za-m
```

Comment: I'm without access to bash at the moment, but I think this should work: `tr A-za-m N-ZA-z` (16 chars)

Comment: @Nabb: Nice to see you, GolfScript-meister! :-D I think your solution here would break the stipulation that "All characters besides A-Z should be copied to the output verbatim".

Comment: @Chris: Yep, looks like you're right.

Comment: @Nabb: No, to me it looks as if he's wrong. Or may you show an example?

Comment: @user unknown: Type in `[\\]^_\`` in the input. It will come back as `NOPQRS` rather than `[\\]^_\``, at least in the version of `tr` I have. (Those are the six characters in ASCII that lie between `Z` and `a`. Obviously, all other characters will work correctly.)

Comment: You're right, I see.

Answer (score 22):

## Python 2, 34 bytes

```
print raw_input().encode('rot13')
```

Comment: -1 I think it is cheating that you are using a built in library.

Comment: I've used them in every code golf I took part in... Also if using python's standard lib is cheating, how is using tr not?

Comment: @Juan: There's no real "hard line", but a lot of it is about how specific the library is. Using transliteration to carry out ROT13 is fine, using the ROT13 builtin is cheating (or at best, a "joke solution").

Comment: @Anon In any case, it's an anwser you just ignore.. It's not off target, there's not any rules set by the OP nor by the community. Sure, maybe mine is not an award winning solution, like the one using tr that kicks ass. But it's not a joke, I'm leveraging the power of python to reduce the count, just like any other would do.

Comment: @Juan I'm just saying that pretty much every code-golf thing I've ever done specified that you cannot use built-in libraries that are specifically designed to solve the solution for you.

Comment: @Glenn: on the contrary, I have never seen a code-golf thing that say so. Neither do codegolf.com, golf.shinh.org or SPOJ SHORTEN.

Comment: See my comment on the other Python solution. `raw_input()` gives only one line.

Comment: @Glenn, I think library functions are fair game. It's up to the golf question to be interesting enough to not be in anyone's library or to specifically exclude.

Answer (score 21):

### Bash - 5 chars

```
rot13
```

Comment: Two downvotes so far (with no comments), but no downvotes for the question. I assume that means it's ok to ask trivial codegolfs but not to give the trivial answer. *Harder* codegolfs please!

Comment: Which bash-version? I don't have a build-in rot13. `bash --version
GNU bash, Version 4.0.33(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: I'd have submitted this as `rot13 - 0 chars`... ;)

Comment: 'tis coreutils my friend, not Bash

Comment: erm... no. my bash (Ubuntu 13.10) says "command not found, you can install this program by `sudo apt-get install bsdgames`"

Comment: Sorry but your not golfing here your running an application that does it for you and there for you not using bash your using the application 'rot13' however i did not downvote

Comment: rot13 is not in coreutils, so this isn't a bash solution *or* a bash+coreutils solution.

Answer (score 17):

### Befunge - <strike>7x30 = 210</strike> 6x26 = 156 characters

New streaming version that supports both upper and lower case and should support unlimited input.

```
v,<               <<     <
  ^-4-9<    >:"A"\`|
     >:"a"\`|     #>:"Z"`|
>~:0`| #    >:"z"`|
,    @ |    <`"m":<v`"M":<
^  +4+9<    ^      <
```

#### The old version

This stores the values inside its own source code. Really shows off how horrible it is to try and output stored values in the same order that you receive them.  Only supports lowercase characters.

```
vp0p11:+1g11<      < <
v                    ^-4-9<
v    >:"a"\`|>:"z"`|>:"m"`|
>~:0`|      >^     >^#
                     ^+4+9<
     >$011g1+0p>12g1+:12p0g:v
               ^           ,_@
```

I'm not sure exactly what limitations this has, using http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html as the interpreter it does appear to break with large inputs.

Comment: You can remove the whitespace at the end of lines.

Answer (score 11):

### Ruby - <strike>60 57 38</strike> 37 chars

Edit: And just realised Ruby strings have a `tr` method.

```
puts$<.read.tr'A-Za-z','N-ZA-Mn-za-m'
```

#### Test

```
input = "The challenge: To read an input of arbitrary length and produce the ROT13 of the input. All characters besides A-Z should be copied to the output verbatim, and case should be preserved if possible.

Any language that can read and write standard streams is fair game."

output = `echo '#{input}' | ruby golf-rot13.rb`

puts "Input:"
puts input
puts "-------"
puts "Output:"
puts output
```

Gives:

```
Input:
The challenge: To read an input of arbitrary length and produce the ROT13 of the input. All characters besides A-Z should be copied to the output verbatim, and case should be preserved if possible.

Any language that can read and write standard streams is fair game.
-------
Output:
Gur punyyratr: Gb ernq na vachg bs neovgenel yratgu naq cebqhpr gur EBG13 bs gur vachg. Nyy punenpgref orfvqrf N-M fubhyq or pbcvrq gb gur bhgchg ireongvz, naq pnfr fubhyq or cerfreirq vs cbffvoyr.

Nal ynathntr gung pna ernq naq jevgr fgnaqneq fgernzf vf snve tnzr.
```

Comment: You don't need the space after `puts`, and 'A-z' is a shortcut for 'A-Za-z'

Comment: @Ventro: Thanks, after a bit of testing it seems `'A-z'` is actually `'A-Z[\]^_`a-z'`, damn ascii having characters between `Z` and `a`.

Comment: Essentially the same but 35 characters: `puts gets.tr'A-Za-z','N-ZA-Mn-za-m'`.

Comment: @Michael: Except `gets` only returns the first line, using $<.read reads until EOF.  The question doesn't say anything about whether the input can contain new lines so I just erred on the side of caution.

Comment: Fair enough, but since the exercise specification only mentioned "arbitrary length" but said nothing about newlines, I'd rather err on the side of brevity in codegolf ;-)

Comment: Updated for Ruby 1.8+ (36 chars, need brackets now)
$><<gets.tr('A-Za-z','N-ZA-Mn-za-m')

Answer (score 10):

## vim, 5 keystrokes

Assuming normal mode and that the text is already written in the buffer:

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>?</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

Or, fallowing vimgolf's conventions:

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>?</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

You can also invoke it as a terminal command, something like this:

```
$ vim -c 'norm g?G' -
< your text here ...
... multiple lines if you want ...
... terminate input with ctrl+D on a blank line >
```

I guess the latter would count as a "program" of 8 characters (`norm g?G`)

Comment: `norm g?G` is short for `normal g?G` that makes 8 chars.

Comment: I think you can safely assume to start out on line 1, so the first `gg` can be left off. I would say 3 keystrokes when the file is open.

Comment: If we use vimgolf's conventions (you start in a vanilla vim having just opened the file, but need to save and quit) we also get 5 (`g?GZZ`).

Answer (score 10):

## R, 37 bytes

```
example("chartr");cat(rot(scan(,"")))
```

`example("chartr")` runs the examples for `chartr`, which includes the `rot` function, which is `ROT13` by default....

Answer (score 7):

`tr///` solution in Perl (39 characters), boilerplate can be removed with `-p`:

```
while(<>){y/a-zA-Z/n-za-mN-ZA-M/;print}
```

Using `-p` (23 characters including the extra switch):

```
perl -pe'y/a-zA-Z/n-za-mN-ZA-M/'
```

Comment: Add 1 char for the p, but please remove the boilerplate!

Answer (score 7):

### C - <strike>83</strike> 79 characters

```
main(c,b){while((c=getchar())>=0)b=c&96,putchar(isalpha(c)?b+1+(c-b+12)%26:c);}
```

Readable version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c, base;

    while ((c = getchar()) >= 0) {
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            base = (c & 96) + 1; /* First letter of the upper or lower case. */
            c = base + (c - base + 13) % 26;
        }
        putchar(c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you including the headers you include in your count?

Comment: @JPvdMerwe: I didn't include any headers in the golfed version, nor did I need to.

Comment: You can use the coma operator before putchar to remove a pair of braces.

Comment: Could you explain main(c,b)? It's the first time i see this.

Comment: also you can write `b=c&96` and move +1 inside putchar. I got your version down to 79 chars.

Comment: @Alexandru: `main(c,b)` abuses the fact that parameters without types default to int, so you don't have to say `int c,b;`.  This is a pretty common golfing technique for C.  Also, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @Alexandru most C compilers support main with any parameters. Also, the original C standard defines that an argument with no type is an int. Thus you get to declare ints without actually writing int.

Comment: One more thing: you can get rid of `b`, replace it with `(c&96)` and replace `c-(c&96)` with `c%32`. Down to 76.

Answer (score 7):

### Python (117 bytes)

Here's a Python version that avoids the `rot13()`-method.

```
import sys
print"".join([chr(x/32*32+1+(x%32+12)%26if 64<x<91or 96<x<123 else x)for x in map(ord,sys.stdin.read())])
```

Comment: raw_input returns one line not all input.

Comment: you need to `import sys` and use `sys.stdin.read()`.

Comment: @Alexandru: will do

Comment: -2 bytes if you eliminate the `[]` to make the list comp a generator: https://tio.run/##FYxBCsMgEADvecUSCGhTLGoRAvlMqIoWo7Jaal5v7WmGOUy@qktR9O7PnLBCucqU0cc6z@ydfCQvh6Q9pLhJsfKVtOVPQRehvAX13Nu@8YSwqWFcSDChGGjUjtbARziPTBLq@xizUrWPDM2hCaW091I/1k7OhJDgG1BPPw

Answer (score 6):

**DC (<strike>111</strike> 108 for the dc itself)**

Ok, here it is in (mostly) dc and some sed and od magic to get it into the right format for the code. If you don't count the input thing (`echo -n MESSAGE |`) it's 160 bytes:

```
od -An -t dC|sed 's/^\ *//;s/\ \{2,3\}/\n/g'|dc -e'[13+26%]sm[65-lmx65+]su[97-lmx97+]sl[96<b64<dPc]sa[91>c]sd[123>e]sb[lux]sc[llxdd]se[ddddlaxlrx]sy[?z0<y]dsrx'
```

As a point of interest, the *dc programme* itself is only a *108 bytes* long, shorter than the non-library python version. It even preserves case and punctuation, and *beats* Javascript in the above submission! If only I could better parse the output of od, or better yet replace it altogether.

EDIT: It's worth noting that the question doesn't indicate a trailing new line `10P` which saves me three further bytes.

EDIT 2: There's no specification for the format of the input, so I assume it's taken in as is convenient for my programme :P

Answer (score 5):

Perl6 (54)

```
$*IN.lines».trans("a..zA..Z"=>"n..za..mN..ZA..M").say
```

Answer (score 5):

## PHP - <s>103</s> <s>98</s> 80 characters

(not using str_rot13())

```
<?=preg_replace('#[a-zA-Z]#e','chr(($x=ord("\0"))-$x%32+1+($x%32+12)%26)',`cat`);
```

Answer (score 5):

### Delphi, 110

```
var c:Char;begin repeat Read(c);Write(Chr(Ord(c)+(Ord(c in['A'..'M'])-Ord(c in['N'..'Z']))*13));until EOF;end.
```

Comment: `var c:Char;begin repeat Read(c);Write(Chr(Ord(c)+(Ord(c in['A'..'M'])-Ord(c in['N'..'Z']))*13));until EOF;end.` saves one character :)

Comment: @Wouter van Nifterick : Good spot! I'll update it accordingly

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 100 characters

```
a%b=([a..b]++)
main=interact$map$toEnum.((0%64$78%90$65%77$91%96$110%122$97%109$[123..])!!).fromEnum
```

Answer (score 5):

## [LispLisp](https://github.com/SYZYGY-DEV333/LispLisp) (16,636)

I'm sorry.

```
((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
  (lisp lisp))
 (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
   ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
    ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
     (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
       ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
        (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
          (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
            ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
             (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
           (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
             ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
              (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
            (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
              ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
               (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
             (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
               ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))))
              (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))))
         ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
          (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))))
      (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
        ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
         (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
           (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
             ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
              (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
               ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))))
            (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
              (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
               ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                 ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                  ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))) (lisp lisp)))))))
             ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
              (((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                  (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                    ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                     (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                   (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                 ((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                    ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                     (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                       ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                        (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                      (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                   (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                    (lisp lisp)))
                  (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                    (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                      ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                       (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                     (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                   (lisp lisp))))
                (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                  ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                   ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                    (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                     ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))) (lisp lisp))))))
                 (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
               ((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                 (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                   ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                    ((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                       (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                         ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                          (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                        (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                      (lisp lisp))
                     ((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                        (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                          ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                           (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                         (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                       (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                         (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                           ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                            (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                          (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                        (lisp lisp)))
                      (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                        ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                         ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                          (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                           ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))) (lisp lisp))))))
                       (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))))
                  (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                   ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                    ((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                      (lisp lisp))
                     (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                       ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                        (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                          ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                           ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                            (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                             ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))) (lisp lisp))))))
                         (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                      (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                       (lisp lisp))))))))
                (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                  ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                   ((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                      (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                        ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                         (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                       (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                     (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                       ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                        (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                          (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                            ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                             (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                           (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                         (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                           (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                             ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                              (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                            (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                          (lisp lisp)))))
                      ((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                        (lisp lisp))
                       (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                         (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                           ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                            (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                          (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                        (lisp lisp)))))
                    (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                      ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                       ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                        (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                         ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                          ((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                             (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                               ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                              (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                            (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                              ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                               (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                 (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                   ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                    (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                                  (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                                (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                  (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                    ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                     (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                                   (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                                 (lisp lisp)))))
                             ((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                               (lisp lisp))
                              (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                  ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                   (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                                 (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                               (lisp lisp)))))
                           ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                            (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                              ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                               (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                             (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))))))))
                     (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))))
                 ((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                    (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                      ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                       (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                     (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                   (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                     ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                      (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                        (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                          ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                           (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                         (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                       (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                         (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                           ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                            (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                          (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                        (lisp lisp)))))
                    ((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                      (lisp lisp))
                     (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                       (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                         ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                          (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                        (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                      (lisp lisp)))))
                  (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                    ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                     ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                      (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                       ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                        (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                          ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                           (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                            ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                             (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))))
                         (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                           (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                            ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                             (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                              ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                               ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))) (lisp lisp)))))))
                          ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                           (((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                               (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                 ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                  (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                                (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                              (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                 (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                   (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                     ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                      (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                                    (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                                  (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                    (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                      ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                       (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                                     (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                                   (lisp lisp)))))
                               ((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                                 (lisp lisp))
                                (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                  (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                    ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                     (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                                   (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                                 (lisp lisp)))))
                             (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                               ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                 (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                   (lisp lisp))
                                  ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))) (lisp lisp))))))
                              (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                            (((((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
                               (lisp lisp))
                              (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                 ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                  (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                    ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                     (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                                   (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                     ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                      ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                       (lisp lisp))))
                                    (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))))
                               (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                 ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                  ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                   ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                    (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))))
                                (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                  (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                    ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                     (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                                   (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                     ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                      (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
                                    (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                      (lisp lisp))
                                     (lisp lisp)))))
                                 ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                  ((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                   (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
                                     ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
                                      (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
                                    (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))))))
                             ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))) (lisp lisp))))))))))))
                   (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))))))))
          (lisp lisp))))
       (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
        ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
         (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))))))
  (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
    (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
      ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
       (lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))))
     (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))))
       ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
        (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))))
      (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
       (lisp lisp)))))
   ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
    (((lisp (lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))) (lisp lisp))
     ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp)))
      ((lisp (lisp (lisp lisp))) (lisp lisp))))))))
```

Comment: Is this an actual language with an implementation? If so, can you please link to it?

Comment: @JoKing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)) [TIO](https://tio.run/#clisp)

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart Yes, Lisp is a language. Lisplisp however, I have found no evidence exists

Comment: @JoKing oh I see. [Maybe he was referring to this?](https://github.com/agrif/lisplisp)

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart No, that's just another Lisp interpreter

Comment: Here's a translator to LazyK (Itself simply an implementation of the SKI Combinator Calculus). https://gist.github.com/SYZYGY-DEV333/d74ca36b9a4c504b25c0a2380203c98d

Answer (score 5):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>200</s> <s>164</s> <s>113</s> 86 bytes

```c
main(){char*s,*t=s;for(gets(s);*s;s++)isalpha(*s)?*s+=(*s&~32)<78?13:-13:0;printf(t);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcY7DsIwDADQq8CCbKeVgA4gTNWVGzBboZ9IJqnibAiuHjo86fnWq8S51reECPjxi2SyhkpvPKUM81gMDJmMzTkMJrouAmQ4kLl@y@HXnfF@uQ6n7tZujrzmEMsEBflb62NUTc3umbK@9n8)

This uses a for-loop which converts each letter into ROT13 using their ASCII values to use lesser bytes. `scanf()`'s parameters are now longer to include spaces in the string, since the previous code revision can't take spaces for input, so now it's longer.

Thanks to ceiling cat for golfing 36 bytes. Thanks to EasyasPi, with the help of ceilingcat, for golfing 51 bytes. Thanks to a stone arachnid for golfing 27 bytes.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf Stack Exchange, Code Golf Stack Exchange! Nice first answer. I don't know C at all, but it looks like bitwise operators work to save bytes. Nice username as well.

Comment: [151 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7BDoIwEETvfgWJiWlFCBUCkiJn/8F4IKXAJmtrWowH9dsrBU087cxkXnZEJLBRvVuDEnhvZVDZsQUdD/XqPzKg@ilzwK8NKEKfYmjM1vJOG9LL0RJLOfgeSjXrMKTQEXuGS51nG3@r4vCafZkvnrGEehEeWcolWhn8iKJYGiVbCJaUX2Sfzkjkkds0auz8t7dzJ4mod8FDG2zjDw) Only In Code Golf™

Comment: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcY7DsIwDADQq8CCbKeVgA4gTNWVGzBboZ9IJqnibAiuHjo86fnWq8S51reECPjxi2SyhkpvPKUM81gMDJmMzTkMJrouAmQ4kLl@y@HXnfF@uQ6n7tZujrzmEMsEBflb62NUTc3umbK@9n8 "C (clang) – Try It Online") using bitwise arithmetic and the `isalpha()` function from `ctype.h`

Answer (score 4):

### PHP - 41 Characters

```
while($r=fgets(STDIN))echo str_rot13($r);
```

Comment: -1 for rep-whoring.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3 (107)

Ok, I promise to stop answering this question now, but I felt compelled to beat the DC answer in Python.  This probably reflects poorly on me as a person :).

```
import sys;[print(x.isalpha()and chr((ord(x)&96)+1+(ord(x)%32+12)%26)or x,end='')for x in sys.stdin.read()]
```

Answer (score 4):

## C: <strike>69</strike> 68 characters

Alright, I know this thread is long dead, but I couldn't stand the (long) C-solution which doesn't even compile on Clang (but does on GCC).

```
main(c){putchar(isalpha(c=getchar())*((c|32)<110?13:-13)+c);main();}
```

<strike>It is probably almost still squeezable.</strike> It certainly was squeezable. And not only was it squeezable, it was possible to make it recursive.

Answer (score 4):

## [CHIQRSX9+](http://esolangs.org/wiki/CHIQRSX9%2B), 1

```
R
```

You just have to use the right tool for the problem.
CHIQRSX9+ is Turing complete, and it can read and write from standard channels with `C`.

Comment: *The language you use should not be invented just for solving this particular code golf. It's been done, trust us, and the joke is old hat.* -- [Source](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info)

Comment: @nyuszika7h The language was invented before this question was written, so it is valid.

Comment: It's still one of the things it was invented for, though. Seems like cheating to me.

Comment: @nyuszika7h And golfscript was invented to win in code-golf challenges. Do you think that is cheating too?

Comment: CHIQRSX9+ is not a programming language by our [usual standards](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/45941). It does not have a clear specification on the `X` instruction, and because the RNG is not seeded, the output of the `X` instruction in the Perl implementation is not consistent across runs, therefore not following a consistent transformational model. This should be deleted.

Comment: @Mego It's hardly fair to apply those standards here when they were written a year after this answer.

Comment: @Mego Does it really matter? If you can find an already existing language that can do the job in 1 character, something is wrong with the question. I'm probably the idiot responsible for all that stupid rules. And the Meta-CodeGolf family is still not forbidden by this definition.

Comment: [MetaGolfScript is forbidden by a different rule](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5076/45941)

Comment: The updated interpreter by ChristopherPeart can satisfy all of the above requirements.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to *robbie0630*

```
ADu)øJD2äRJ‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0aVU8/AOLxejw0uCvB41LPz/3zUvOT8lVTckw7NYpyDH1bHYVREA)

**Explanation**

```
ADu           # push lower-case and uppercase alphabet
   )øJ        # zip, flatten and join, producing aAbB..zZ
      D2äRJ   # split a copy in 2 pieces, reverse and join producing nNoO..mM
           ‡  # translate input by replacing members of the alphabet 
              # with the corresponding member of the rot-13 alphabet
              # implicitly display
```

Comment: I ran through this with `--debug`, and it seems like the `˜` is a no-op in this case and can be cut out.

Comment: @robbie0630: True. No idea why I had that in. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

## x86-16 Machine Code, IBM PC DOS, 37 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: b408 cd21 3c20 7e1c 8ad0 0c20 3c61 7c0e  ...!< ~.... <a|.
00000010: 3c7a 7f0a b60d 3c6e 7c02 b6f3 02d6 b402  <z....<n|.......
00000020: cd21 ebdc c3                             .!...
```

Build and test using `xxd -r`

**Unassembled listing:**

```
        START: 
B4 08       MOV  AH, 8          ; DOS API read char from STDIN (no echo) 
CD 21       INT  21H            ; read char into AL 
3C 20       CMP  AL, ' '        ; is any non-printable control char?
7E 1C       JL   EXIT           ; if so, end 
8A D0       MOV  DL, AL         ; save original char in DL 
0C 20       OR   AL, 'a'-'A'    ; lowercase the char 
3C 61       CMP  AL, 'a'        ; is char less than 'a'? 
7C 0E       JL   WRCHR          ; if so, do not convert 
3C 7A       CMP  AL, 'z'        ; is char greater than 'z'? 
7F 0A       JG   WRCHR          ; if so, do not convert 
B6 0D       MOV  DH, 'n'-'a'    ; add or subtract 13 
3C 6E       CMP  AL, 'n'        ; is char less than 'n'? 
7C 02       JL   ADD13          ; if so, add 13 
B6 F3       MOV  DH, 'a'-'n'    ; otherwise add -13 
        ADD13: 
02 D6       ADD  DL, DH         ; add 13 or -13
        WRCHR: 
B4 02       MOV  AH, 2          ; DOS API write char to STDOUT 
CD 21       INT  21H            ; write char in DL 
EB DC       JMP  START          ; keep looping 
        EXIT: 
C3           RET                ; return to DOS
```

As a standalone PC DOS executable program.  Input is via `STDIN`, output to `STDOUT`.

[image]

Re-submitting answer to conform to `STDIN` challenge requirement.

Answer (score 3):

**Java 251 chars**

```
public class r{public static void main(String[] a){String s = a[0];for(int i=0;i<s.length();){char c=s.charAt(i++);if(c>='a'&&c<='m')c+=13;else if(c>='n'&&c<='z')c-= 13;else if(c>='A'&&c<='M')c+=13;else if(c>='A'&&c <='Z')c-=13;System.out.print(c);}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (165)

```
a=prompt();y="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";b=y[s="substr"](13)+y[s](0,13);y+=y[l="toLowerCase"]();b+=b[l]();o='';for(i=0;a[i];i++)o+=b[y.indexOf(a[i])]||a[i];alert(o)
```

or (167) as previous Javascript solution, assuming readLine and print:

```
a=readLine();y="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";b=y[s="substr"](13)+y[s](0,13);y+=y[l="toLowerCase"]();b+=b[l]();o='';for(i=0;a[i];i++)o+=b[y.indexOf(a[i])]||a[i];print(o)
```

Answer (score 3):

### C, 136 bytes

I have never felt like any of my solutions are good enough to post on here, but made this for fun, and figured that it will be my gateway drug into code golf.

```
#define z(x) c>=x&&c<x+13
#define q(w) c>=w&&c<w+13
main(c){for(;(c=getchar())>=0;putchar(z('A')||z('a')?c+13:q('M')||q('m')?c-13:c));}
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange. Great first answer. And just for the record, we all feel that way sometimes, just know that anything that you create is "good enough" somewhere.

Comment: Everything here on PPCG is just for fun (or imaginary internet points) -- please, don't feel the work you've done to craft a solution isn't "good enough"

Comment: Thanks for all the support.  I think posting something was all I needed to get my head in gear.  I am going to try my hand at more of these challenges soon.

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 49 bytes

```
0i::"{`"@(@)*84**-::"AZ"@(@)+:}?$"4"-2d*%"A"+{?$o
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yDTykqpOkHJQcNBU8vCREtLF8h3jALzta1q7VWUTJR0jVK0VJUclbSr7VXy///3SM3JyddRKM8vyklRBAA)

**Explanation**

`0i`
On each loop we initialize the stack with **0** and an input character.
The **0** will be used as a dummy to perform rot-13 operations on when the input isn't a letter.

`` ::"{`"@(@)*84**- ``
Convert lowercase letters into uppercase for easier future operations.

`::"AZ"@(@)+:}?$`
If the character isn't an uppercase letter, use the **0** instead.

`"4"-2d*%"A"+`
ROT-13 operation. Subtract **52**, mod by **13** and add **65** to get an uppercase letter.

`{?$`
If the character wasn't an uppercase before the ROT-13 operations, use the saved character instead.

`o`
Print as a character.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell - 112 characters

```
r l=drop 13 l++take 13 l
t=['a'..'z']
s=['A'..'Z']
main=interact$map(\x->maybe x id$lookup x$zip(t++s)$r t++r s)
```

Answer (score 2):

**JavaScript 1.8, 106**

`alert(prompt().replace(/\w/g,function(c)String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt()+(c.toLowerCase()<'n'?13:-13))))`

**JavaScript, 115**

`alert(prompt().replace(/\w/g,function(c){return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt()+(c.toLowerCase()<'n'?13:-13))}))`

This solution solves the problem by adding 13 to the character code if the character in question is in the first half of the alphabet, or subtracting 13 if it's in the second half.

Comment: You can save **7** characters by replacing `+(c.toLowerCase()<'n'?13:-13))` with `-13+26*/[a-m]/i.test(c)`.

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, noncompeting (language postdates challenge)

Jolf, 3 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=LFJp)

```
,Ri
,R  rot13
  i the input
```

Or, with new implicit input, `,R`.

I'm sorry, but I'm not. I implemented this because it appears often in code-breaking puzzles, which I use Jolf a lot for, and recently used in an ARG. \o/

A longer one ([try that one here](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=z4FpIlslXSLOs3BXcHVkLnBXcDJwdSt0MyBpzrNI)):

```
ρi"[%]"γpWpud.pWp2pu+t3 iγH
ρi                           regex replace input
  "[%]"                      "[...]" following
        pWpu                 "abc...xyzABC....XYZ"
       γ                     γ = that
            d                functional replace
             .         _iγH  the index on the alphabet that the element is
                p2pu         shift uppercase alphabet
                    +t3      over thirteen
              pW             upper + lower of that
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 69 bytes

```julia
(x->(c=Char(x);print(c+isletter(c)*13*(-1)^(x&31>13)))).(read(stdin))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcmxCsIwEADQ3a84OshdpULIKHZQcRBBBGchpMGm1qRcEo3@fNS3viGNVolcCuamRb3e9oox02pi6yLqhQ2jidEwaqqFrLERdMU8l6IVkn6WyEZ1GGJnHVEp1aU3cE5W32HD/uVg7/PskB5TgNPTMPz7qD5v2Plb9QU)

#### Explanation

Most of the code is an anonymous function that takes an integer codepoint and prints the corresponding ROT-13'd character:

```julia
x->(c=Char(x);print(c+isletter(c)*13*(-1)^(x&31>13)))

x->(                                                )  # Anonymous function of x
    c=Char(x);                                         # Cast x to Char and save as c
                    c+                                 # Start with c and add to its codepoint:
                      isletter(c)*                     # If c is not a letter, the rest of this is
                                                       # multiplied by 0
                                  13*(-1)^(       )    # 13, times +/- 1 according to:
                                           x&31>13     # Low 5 bits of x are greater than 13
                                                       # I.e. x > 'M' (if x is uppercase) or x > 'm'
                                                       # (if x is lowercase)
              print(                               )   # Output the resulting character
```

We then apply this function, vectorized, to the array of (integer) codepoints returned by `read(stdin)`.

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcmxCsIwEADQ3a84OshdpULIbAYVBxFEcBZCGmy0JuWSaBT/PeJb3y2PTotSK1vdY0y987T8qtKpiZ1PiGa1GTRjIVq4ONqULKOhVsgWO0EXLHMplJBEtTbnwcIpO3OHNYeXh10os31@TBGOT8vw74P@vGEbrs0P)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 65 bytes

```javascript
o=>(b=Buffer)(b(o).map(c=>c%32<26&c>64?(c%32+13)%26+c-c%32:c))+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdBCoMwEADAr/Ris0tQaJQcShPBU8/@IK6xtGxdibY@P@Lc5hP@YaX0XrZyljHm3mVxHgbX/aYpJoQBBKtvWICcp6I2D2Ov5G3Twjl9q7EwVlN57k6IWqlMMq/CsWJ5QQ/qGZnlskviUSHmAw)

```javascript
o=>(                    // Define a function taking o and r
  b = Buffer            // Assign b to Buffer
)(                      // And call on...
  b(o).map(c=>          // a Buffer of the charcodes of o, mapped to...
    c%32<26&c>64        // If the character is alphabetical - charcode%32 is less than 26, charcode is >64
      ?                 // Then
    (c%32+13)%26+c-c%32 // Rot-13 the character - Mod 32, add 13, mod 26, add correct number depending on whether it's uppercase of lowercase.
    :c)                 // Else return the original string
 ) + ''                 // Coerce to string
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Atto-8](https://github.com/Bricktech2000/Atto-8) Machine Code, 23 bytes

[Decoded](https://github.com/Bricktech2000/Atto-8/tree/master/dec) as hex:

```
E8 00 E0 C0 20 A0 61 84 00 0D 85 0D 90 0D 85 F2 90 D0 80 00 E1 01 E3
```

Commented [disassembly](https://github.com/Bricktech2000/Atto-8/tree/master/dasm) listing:

```
# Generated by Dasm

main!
  nop @dyn        # padding for alignment
  x00 lda         # read from standard input
  ld0 x20 orr     # clone and convert to lowercase
  x61 sub         # map lowercase alphabet to 0-25
  x00             # default offset is 0
  x0D su2 x0D iff # if between a-m, offset is 13
  x0D su2 xF2 iff # if between n-z, offset is -13
  st0 add         # add offset to original input
  x00 sta         # write to standard output
  x01 sti         # loop back to start
```

Answer (score 1):

### K, 31

```
{x^(,/{x!(13_x),13#x}'.Q`A`a)x}
```

Comment: `{x^a(,/-13 13#\:a:.Q.A)?x}` for **26 bytes**

Comment: Assuming only rot13'ing upper case letters is acceptable, `{x^a(,/|0 13_a:.Q.A)?x}` for 23 bytes. Handling both upper and lower case can be done in 29 by swapping the inner lambda in @tmartin's answer for `{x!,/|0 13_x}`.

Answer (score 1):

### Tcl, 74 chars

```
package require [set c tcl::transform::rot];$c 13 stdin;fcopy stdin stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

## [pyg-i](https://gist.github.com/ids1024/8c3c3a0653566ada4149) - 76 Bytes

```
P(STDI.read().t({a:a-13 if(77<a<91)or a>109 else a+13 for a in M(ord,STl)}))
```

Python Equivient:

```
import sys,string
print(sys.stdin.read().translate({a:a-13 if(77<a<91)or a>109 else a+13 for a in map(ord,string.ascii_letters)}))
```

Comment: Invalid because the interpreter is not available.

Comment: @cat Somehow I got the url wrong. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (103)

Reused `maybe c id $ lookup c` from [jloy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1611/12668).

```
main=interact$map(\c->maybe c id$lookup c$[['a'..'z'],['A'..'Z']]>>=zip<*>uncurry(flip(++)).splitAt 13)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python: 60 bytes

```
lambda s:''.join([chr((ord(c.lower())-84)%26+97)for c in s])
```

The only thing I don't like is having that .lower() in there. Any suggestions?

edit: I can get rid of the .lower(), and handle capitals better, but it's 94 bytes now:

```
lambda s:''.join([chr((ord(c)-(52if ord(c)<97else 84))%26+(65if ord(c)<97else 97))for c in s])
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 94 bytes

```
s=>{var r="";foreach(var c in s)r+=(char)(Char.IsLetter(c)?(c|32)<110?c+13:c-13:c);return r;};
```

Anonymous function which returns the string of characters rotated by 13 places, based on [this C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11093/58437) from [Fors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7682/fors). Works for any lower or upper letters while keeping other input the same.

Full program with ungolfed method and test cases:

```
using System;

namespace ROT13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<string, string> f =
            s =>
            {
                var r = "";
                foreach (var c in s)
                    r += (char)(Char.IsLetter(c) ? (c | 32) < 110 ? c + 13 : c - 13 : c);
                return r;
            };

            Console.WriteLine(f("TOO MANY SECRETS!"));   // GBB ZNAL FRPERGF!
            Console.WriteLine(f("too many secrets!"));   // gbb znal frpergf!
            Console.WriteLine(f("gbb znal frpergf!"));   // too many secrets!
            Console.WriteLine(f("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890,./"));
// NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm1234567890,./
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>72</s> 67 bytes

Edit: -5 bytes thanks to James Holderness

```
<,<v!:+*"a"*`"`"\`\"{":\*"G"*`"@"\`\"[":::_@#+1:~
+0|_\"N"%6-55*1+%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/30bHpkzRSltLKVFJK0EpQSkmIUapWskqRkvJHSTgABaIVrKysop3UNY2tKrj0jaoiY9R8lNSNdM1NdUy1Fb9/z8xKTklNS09IzMrOyc3L7@gsKi4pLSsvKKySsHRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsPCIySkHRQVkFAA)

Kinda disappointed in the previous Befunge answers, so I wrote one with much less whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ØAṙ13,µ;Œlyɠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDMeHO2caGusc2mp9dFJO5ckF//97AKXydRTC84tyUhQB)

This takes input from STDIN

### How it works

```
ØAṙ13,µ;Œlyɠ - Main link. Takes no arguments
ØA           - "ABC...XYZ"
  ṙ13        - Rotate 13 steps to the left
     ,       - Pair with the unaltered alphabet
      µ      - Begin a new link with ['NOP...KLM', 'ABC...XYZ'] as argument
        Œl   - Lowercase; ['nop...klm', 'abc..xyz']
       ;     - Concatenate; ['NOP...KLM', 'ABC...XYZ', 'nop...klm', 'abc..xyz']    
           ɠ - Read a line from STDIN
          y  - Transliterate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 13 bytes

```
13+T`zlZL`l_L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/39BYOyShKifKJyEn3uf//9CiysokHQWvpNTKQkUA)

The straightforward transliteration that directly applies ROT13 would be 2 bytes longer [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PyQhT7cqUTfXTzfKJyHH5/9/j9ScnHwdhfD8opwURQA)

#### Explanation

The transliteration stage here is wrapped in a loop stage making it run 13 times (or until the string is not transformed anymore, which can only happen if the input string has no alphabetic characters).

In the transliteration, characters in `zlZL` are transformed into the characters at the same positions in `l_L`. Here, `z` and `Z` are exactly what they look like, while `l` and `L` get converted into the lowercase and uppercase alphabets. The final letters of those alphabets are ignored because they already appear earlier in the string, and `_` is just a placeholder to make the uppercase alphabet line up correctly. The result is transforming each letter into the next one (a->b,b->c,...,z->a); doing this 13 times is ROT13.

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 77 bytes

```powershell
-join($args|% t*y|%{[char]((("$_"-match'[a-m]')-("$_"-match'[n-z]'))*13+$_)})
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

-join($args|% t*y|%{[char]((("$_"-match'[a-m]')-("$_"-match'[n-z]'))*13+$_)})

}

@(

,("Hello!","Uryyb!")
,("HELLO","URYYB")
,("URYYB","HELLO")
,("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm")
,("Why did the chicken cross the road?
Gb trg gb gur bgure fvqr!",
"Jul qvq gur puvpxra pebff gur ebnq?
To get to the other side!")

) | % {
    $s,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $s
    "$($result-eq$expected): $result"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: Uryyb!
True: URYYB
True: HELLO
True: NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm
True: Jul qvq gur puvpxra pebff gur ebnq?
To get to the other side!
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 70 bytes

```python
a=input()
for i in a:print(end=i.isalpha()*chr(65+(ord(i)-52)%26)or i)
```

Comment: Your proposed solution does not work with lowercase letters. It's not explicitely specified in the challenge though, so I'm not sure if your answer is valid.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - 27 Bytes

```
<?=str_rot13(fgets(STDIN));
```

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz/), 176 bytes

```
2a2x1v6a8m2x2v9a4a2x3v9a5a2x4v5a2x5v9a4a2x6v9a5a2x7v1x1f1r3x1v7e3x5v5g3x2v2g8f0x1x2f3x4v3l8f0x1x3f3x3v4g9a4a8f0x1x4f9s4s8f0x1x5f3x7v6l8f0x1x6f3x6v4g9a4a8f0x1x7f0a0x1x8f1o1f0x1f
```

The most involved naz solution I've written so far. This program subtracts 13 from every letter in standard input that's greater than M, and adds 13 to every other letter - whether lowercase or uppercase.

It does use a lot of logic to determine what's a letter or not, so I wouldn't be surprised if this could be improved upon.

Works for any input string terminated with the control character STX (U+0002).

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
2a2x1v                     # Set variable 1 equal to 2
6a8m2x2v                   # Set variable 2 equal to 64 ("@")
9a4a2x3v                   # Set variable 3 equal to 77 ("M")
9a5a2x4v                   # Set variable 4 equal to 91 ("[")
5a2x5v                     # Set variable 5 equal to 96 ("`")
9a4a2x6v                   # Set variable 6 equal to 109 ("m")
9a5a2x7v                   # Set variable 7 equal to 123 ("{")
1x1f                       # Function 1
    1r                     # Read a byte of input
      3x1v7e               # Jump to function 7 if it equals variable 1
            3x5v5g         # Jump to function 5 if it's greater than variable 5
                  3x2v2g   # Jump to function 2 if it's greater than variable 2
                        8f # Otherwise, jump to function 8
1x2f                       # Function 2
    3x4v3l                 # Jump to function 3 if the register is less than variable 4
          8f               # Otherwise, jump to function 8
1x3f                       # Function 3
    3x3v4g                 # Jump to function 4 if the register is greater than variable 3
          9a4a             # Otherwise, add 13 to the register,
              8f           # then jump to function 8
1x4f                       # Function 4
    9s4s8f                 # Subtract 13 from the register, then jump to function 8
1x5f                       # Function 5
    3x7v6l                 # Jump to function 6 if the register is less than variable 7
          8f               # Otherwise, jump to function 8
1x6f                       # Function 6
    3x6v4g                 # Jump to function 4 if the register is greater than variable 6
          9a4a             # Otherwise, add 13 to the register,
              8f           # then jump to function 8
1x7f                       # Function 7
    0a                     # Add 0 to the register
1x8f                       # Function 8
    1o1f                   # Output, then jump to function 1
1f                         # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
kB½(nn13ǓĿ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kB%C2%BD%28nn13%C7%93%C4%BF&inputs=Hello%2C%20world!&header=&footer=)

-4 thx to lyxal

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kB%C2%BD%28nn13%C7%93%C4%BF&inputs=Hello%2C%20world!&header=&footer=) for 11 bytes.

Comment: @lyxal Thanks, next learn to count!

Answer (score 1):

## [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>147</s> 8+82 = 90 bytes

`-lordchr` argument

```
BEGIN{RS=".|";ORS=e}$0=RT~/[A-Za-z]/?chr(ord(RT)+(ord(tolower(RT))>109?-13:13)):RT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVNNU9swEL3vr9BkeiDTxiHDqXSAgZZSaAs0pNDS6WFtr22BvEpXchzTj5/eVJaHA729t7vafdonYXu/2Rwdn5ye/5xf7Y2SX6NXFwHQ72fbe/PFn@m3w8ktTh6@Tw@ySras5Fvzxfh5BN4a25L0gfH@bPvlwWS2szvbGY9354vN5vzi8tP8avH5@ubL19vDo9dvjt@evDs9e//hI9vlD3G@WbXr7gHTLKeirPTdvakB2rZNikakaBIr5VSsn@20YZhLKl8bgGMujXaVijHlK/Qq1ihvlfUVyZABOMyyADSXfSYkVMN6rUYxO1K5zry2jNIpy6rulOucpzpRAFe2JsVYk1OaM9PklL8IPWwSeqYpqsm@YmsZML1rJMyLvA2TCbCKrAFkHxGWkKK577Hlbh2IDJggpYgEMkMSKy47oTVkgmXPlsQeKE1dT8TaAohjQjDEedUNWBsgkaGIqIAC00GTYxsUhVVGUhGUZHropYOSMerzyCWU4RxHFhohaI5irnENetC1CqrOGqY4pK1QikAFB0YMcPO/F5qHnWsJolYkjp4UodBjPI8tHo85hcul0ZQnahGkTaNO7aJ9lk2nILN1qkM0eKda7SuFmW/QqJqQe6/T8AZUi50LbiEPHoSdsBtWgsXTuwuuNEcjiPUKBWQgAdjBIEqDRY6k6Ekh5MBXTfShbCr/1y57KW4zMeF64YP8Aw)

After some thought, I realized it is possible to explore GNU AWK's `ordchr` extension to return the ASCII value of a character, saving tons of bytes. The ROT13 algorithm identifies if the letter is in the first or second half of the alphabet, adding of subtracting 13 to its ASCII value, accordingly.

This code transforms every character as Record Separator, then substitutes every `$0` (formerly null) for the matching record separator (`RT`): ROT13 modified, if it's a letter; or itself, if not.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 65 bytes

```
ir[:'@Gf(123)Lf'ZGf'aLfp*!**[p'ZGsp(13)+'Z(32)l*+G[p(26)-0]p0]po]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zKNpK3cE9TcPQyFjTJ009yj1NPdEnrUBLUUsrugDILS7QMDTW1FaP0jA20szR0naPLtAwMtPUNYgtAKL82P//lUIyMosVMovz1EsU/L11FIoy0zNK7JV0FIoTM1MUyjMSS1LLUov0AA)

I'm enjoying learning Ly, so even though this is an old challenge I decided to give it a shot...

This is pretty brute force and the result isn't short compared to other entries.  But it does show how to do things like `if-then` conditional blocks in Ly, so maybe someone will find it useful?

This bit reads in a line of input as codepoints, reverses the stack, then loops through each character/codepoint.  At the end of the loop the character is printed, rot13'd or not.

```
ir[                                                            o]
```

The first thing to do is duplicate the character with `:` since we need to do two operations and it's easier to make a copy of the character on the stack now and then do the first one.  That first test checks to see if the current character is in `"a-z"` or `"A-Z"`.  It does that by stacking the results from 4 comparisons, `>=A` `>Z` `>=a` and `>z`.  Then it combines those `0|1` results mathematically to figure out if we're in the right range.

```
   :'@Gf(123)Lf'ZGf'aLfp*!**
```

Then the pattern I've found works for `if-then` is used to conditionally apply the rot-13 logic only when we get an alphabetic character.  That pattern is `...test...[p...then-code...0]p`.  So in this case that's these bits.

```
                            [p                              0]p
```

And the code to apply the rotation starts by figuring out and remembering if the character is uppercase or not.  After the `s` command, the backup cell will be `1|0` to indicated whether or not the character is uppercase.

```
                              'ZGsp
```

After that, the code adds 13 to the codepoint, then constructs what the max codepoint value is.  It's either `Z` or `z` depending on the case of the original character.  The `l` command pushed the backup cell (upper/lower flag) onto the stack so we use that to switch the `Z` to `z` if necessary.

```
                                   (13)+'Z(32)l*+
```

Once that max codepoint is on the stack the code conditionally subtracts `26` if the rotated number it too high.

```
                                                 G[p(26)-0]p
```

At that point, the character we want to print is on top of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

## SM83/Z80, 29 bytes

Input string at `(de)`, output to `(hl)`.

- SM83 version

```
1A 13 47 CB AF D6 41 38
0E FE 1A 30 0A FE 0D 78
38 02 D6 1A C6 0D 47 78
22 B7 20 E4 C9
```

- Z80 version (changes in »German guillemets« except for second bytes of `jr` for same effective offset¹)

```
1A 13 47 CB AF D6 41 38
10 FE 1A 30 0C FE 0D 78
38 04 D6 1A C6 0D 47»70
23 04 10«E6 C9
```

Disassembly and explanation:

```
rot13:
    ld a,(de)       ; 1A        load character
    inc de          ; 13        increment
    ld b,a          ; 47        save copy
    res 5,a         ; CB AF     clear fifth bit
    sub 65          ; D6 41     subtract 'A'
    jr c,put        ; 38 0E/10  if borrowed, wasn't letter
    cp 26           ; FE 1A     is it 26 or more now?
    jr nc,put       ; 30 0A/0C  if didn't borrow, wasn't letter
    cp 13           ; FE 0D     compare against 13
    ld a,b          ; 78        load original
    jr c,notsub     ; 38 02/04  if carry, was greater than 13
    sub 26          ; D6 1A     subtract 26 if was greater
notsub:
    add 13          ; C6 0D     add 13 either way
    ld b,a          ; 47        store into b
put:                ;           b now contains rot13 version
#ifdef SM83
    ld a,b          ; 78        move into a
    ld (hl+),a      ; 22        store and increment
    or a            ; B7        test if zero
    jr nz,rot13     ; 20 E4     if not, loop
#else
    ld (hl),b       ; 70        store
    inc hl          ; 23        and increment
    inc b           ; 04        if b was 0, it's now 1
    djnz rot13      ; 10 E6     jump back if b is 1 (and decrement)
#endif
    ret             ; C9        return
```

It's a bit interesting that both CPUs have a way of saving a byte that the other doesn't. The SM83 has autoincrement addressing, while the Z80 has a way to jump if `b` is 1.

¹ Apparently Z80 relative jump instructions are measured from the start, while SM83's are from the end. (So `18 00` is an infinite loop for Z80 and a three-cycle two-byte no-op for SM83.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 129 bytes

```
vv2++3a-A'<
 a    > Ko= h-A'.<
 #  >@o Ko<>.'Zh-=oK
>wI.=>.'a-h=oK Ko<
 *  >^#va2++3a-a'<
 6    +*   >.'zh-=oK
 >+%'A^>6+%'a+oKo<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/7@szEhb2zhR11HdhkshUQEI7BS8820VMoAiekAhZaCAQz5QyMZOTz0qQ9c235vLrtxTzxbITdTNAHJBclwKWkB1ccpliRDTEkGmmYFM09YCGamnXgXRqmCnraruGGdnBqQStfOBWv//90jNycnXUQjPL8pJUQQA)

### Ungolfed

```
v                      >oK
                 >.'A-h=oK
    >@     >.'Zh-=oK   >'A-a3++2a*6+%'A+oK
                 >oK
>wI.=>.'a-h=oK
                 >'a-a3++2a*6+%'a+oK
    >^     >.'zh-=oK
                 >oK
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 60 bytes

```python
import this
print("".join(this.d.get(c,c)for c in input()))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 40 bytes

```
`c$@[!256;c@!26;:;(c:"aA"+\:)26!-13+!26]
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs0pIVnGIVjQyNbNOdlA0MrO2stZItlJKdFTSjrHSNDJT1DU01gaKx3JxpTkoeaTm5OTrKJTnF+WkKCpxAQDY1Q9J)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6 (155 bytes)

Here is a Caesar cipher that preserves case in in ES6.

```js
// 155 bytes
r=s=>((f,n,m,u,l)=>[...s].map(c=>(x=>x>=u&&x<=u+n?f((x-u+m)%n+u):x>=l&&x<=l+n?f((x-l+m)%n+l):c)(c.charCodeAt())).join(''))(String.fromCharCode,26,13,65,97)

// Begin unit tests
mocha.setup('bdd')
const { expect } = chai
const testCases = [{
  input: "Hello, world!",
  output: "Uryyb, jbeyq!",
}, {
  input: "Code Golf and Coding Challenges is awesome.",
  output: "Pbqr Tbys naq Pbqvat Punyyratrf vf njrfbzr.",
}, {
  input: "Mod abuse!1!!1",
  output: "Zbq nohfr!1!!1",
}]
describe('Caesar cipher (ROT13)', () => {
    it('are all equal', () => {
    for (let { input, output } of testCases) {
      expect(r(input)).to.equal(output)
    }
  })
})
mocha.run()
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.3.4/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.4.1/chai.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.3.4/mocha.js"></script>
<div id="mocha"></div>
```

Here is one that is **187 bytes** (**+32 bytes**), but no code duplication:

```js
r=s=>((b,f,n,m,u,l)=>[...s].map(c=>(x=>b(u,x,n)?f(u,x,n,m):b(l,x,n)?f(l,x,n,m):c)(c.charCodeAt())).join(''))((v,x,n)=>x>=v&&x<=v+n,(v,x,n,m)=>String.fromCharCode((x-v+m)%n+v),26,13,65,97)
```

At **192 bytes** (**+37 bytes**), this one is a bit larger, but it builds a lookup and does regex replace:

```js
r=s=>(l=>s.replace(/\w/g,c=>l[c]))(((f,z)=>f(z.map(c=>c.toLowerCase()),f(z,{})))((s,o)=>s.reduce((m,c,i)=>({...m,[c]:s[(i+13)%26]}),o),Array.from({length:26},(_,i)=>String.fromCharCode(i+65))))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Scala 108

```
def m(a:Int,z:Int,c:Int)=if(c>=a&&c<z)a+((c-a+13)%26)else c
"Ok?".map(c=>print(m(65,91,m(97,123,c)).toChar))
```

ungolfed:

```
def m (a: Int, z:Int, c:Int) = if (c >= a && c <= z) a+((c-a+13)%26) else c
"Ok?".foreach (c => print (m ('A', 'Z', m ('a', 'z', c)).toChar))
```

result:

```
Bx?
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mathematica 102**

```
StringReplace[Input[],
Join@@Table[Rule@@FromCharacterCode/@{i+c,Mod[i+13,26]+c},{c,{65,97}},{i,0,25}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 135

```
s=prompt(),o='',i=0
while((c=s.charCodeAt(i++)))c+=c>64&&c<91?c<52?13:-13:c>96&&c<123?c<109?13:-13:0,o+=String.fromCharCode(c)
alert(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala (96 chars)

```scala
def r(s:String)=s.map{c⇒val m = if(c<91)65 else 97
if(c.isLetter)
((c+13-m)%26+m).toChar
else c}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>32</s> 29 bytes

```
a.{~3&u:+13*2|&.>:'@MZ`mz'&I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WTyFRr7rOWK3UStvQWMuoRk3PzkrdwTcqIbdKXc1T739qcka@QpqCerWhQZxFrYKtQmlGYmFqUaFCVVllZVlSovp/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 28 bytes

```
c_d)è"%l")?Z|H)<#n?Z+D:Z-D:Z
```

[Try it!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=Y19kKegiJWwiKT9afEgpPCNuP1orRDpaLUQ6Wg==&input=IlRPTyBNQU5ZIFNFQ1JFVFMhIGdiYiB6bmFsIGZycGVyZ2YhIg==)

```
c_d)è"%l")?Z|H)<#n?Z+D:Z-D:Z
c_                                # map input string through a function
  d)è"%l")?                       # regex check if current character is a letter
           Z|H)<#n?               # is it less than the letter n?
                   Z+D:           # if yes, then add 13
                       Z-D:       # otherwise, subtract 13
                           Z      # not a letter, do not transform
```

Comment: [20 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a1&code=clxsX2NffEggPCNuP1orRDpaLUQ=&input=IlRPTyBNQU5ZIFNFQ1JFVFMhIGdiYiB6bmFsIGZycGVyZ2YhIg==) using `r`eplace and switching to v2.0a1. There must be a shorter way, though.

Comment: [18 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a1&code=clxsX2NfJUg8RT9aK0Q6Wi1E&input=IlRPTyBNQU5ZIFNFQ1JFVFMhIGdiYiB6bmFsIGZycGVyZ2YhIg==)

Comment: Nice - I had not tried the beta version yet. Looks like regex may have improved?

Comment: Yeah, but it's bugged to hell at the moment - only single character class work; anything wrapped in `/` won't.

Comment: [17 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a1&code=clxsX2NfK0QqKFolSDxFqko=&input=IlRPTyBNQU5ZIFNFQ1JFVFMhIGdiYiB6bmFsIGZycGVyZ2YhIg==).

Answer (score 0):

## [T-SQL](https://www.microsoft.com/sql-server), 80 bytes

The [TRANSLATE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function was introduced in SQL Server 2017.

Input is taken from the column `I` of the table `T`.

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(I,A+B,B+A)FROM(VALUES('ABCDEFGHIJKLM','NOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))V(A,B),T
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e2e2a/1)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/), 79 bytes

Builtins only. [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVtBQ6Vao9jKStOwVrOgKDOvJE1BpTpbP9pRNypRtypWHyirrKmioVFlq5xtY2lob2BlbKRjZqpdpa2hnK1raqRbpalqZKapWVv7//9/xySv0qLUIBNjU10HZRUA)

```zsh
for k (${(s::)1})printf ${k/[A-Za-z]/${(#)$((z=#k<91?0:32,65+z+(#k-52-z)%26))}}
```

**Explanation**

```
for k (${(s::)1})  # for each letter $k of the argument $1, loop
&&printf ${..}     # and print the value of expression ${..}, per `man zshexpn`
${k/[A-Za-z]/      # if $k is a letter, replace it with the following stuff,
                   #    otherwise leave it (implicit)
${(#)..}           # convert decimal (in the following expression) to ascii char
$((..))            # math expression
                   #    n.b.: #k is the ascii value (ord) of $k
#k<91?             # ternary: if #k<91, i.e $k is uppercase
65+(#k-52)%26      #    rotate uppercase
:97+(#k-84)%26     #    otherwise, rotate lowercase
```

<sub>Previous solutions: <s>[126](https://tio.run/##Pc29CsIwEADg3ac4yBkSSof0R0rboa6OToFLQASLXapc62LaZ48Kxfkbvvd0j5GVfvIwzj04h0RCVF6ZPEGTKCHQpmj0Pjtov@sfDBaGETCoqa61WZugiKBr0UqJtnUE3kvJUGZ6WX7kLn8Lm1XF17YQ7RpjPF5PL76di7xMO4Ef)</s>, <s>[112](https://tio.run/##NcxNC4IwGADgu79isDfYkh3mF@IuDQki6FIdRlPCZJIXlc0uir990aHbc3oW9/bOzOM0o1Lejs@LvJcnbwmdbD/MHaoq0BrjvCY8DoGHBGNQDDjdRRmtg260SCECK3FFQflG17ZxBoFC/RBoyR41tSiNhNANW37OEyH2/xyUEMY17ea9l6/zx5prEqfsgOEL)</s>, <s>[106](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWpJfUKLg7BjsGu/rGOLs8b9IQ7OgKDOvJE0hJkYlOlpZ2SJWw9BYW8VQW0NZWSVCV8VQU9XITDOWKy2/SCFCQUOlWqPYykrTsFazOjmxOFVBJUKhOtpRNypWs0jB1MjaOjpRtwrEtjCxttaCGa0SYV1b@///f8ckr9Ki1CATY1NdB2UVAA)</s>, <s>[99](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVtBQ6Vao9jKStOwVrOgKDOvJE1BpVqlOls/2lE3KlYfKKmsqaKhYWaqraESrZwdq2tqpKlqZKapWVurH52oW4VQYmkOU2JhAlPy//9/xySv0qLUIBNjU10HZRUA)</s>, <s>[88](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVtBQ6Vao9jKStOwVjPLViVaOTtWTa2gKDOvJE1BpTpbP9pRNypRtypWH6hMWVNFQyPLxtLQ3sxUWyNL19RIU9XIzMrSHMSxMAFxNDVra////@@Y5FValBpkYmyq66CsAgA)</s>, <s>[82](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVtBQ6Vao9jKStOwVrOgKDOvJE1BpTpbP9pRNypRtypWHyirrKmioaGcbWNpaG9mqg1k6ZoaaaoamVlZmoN5FiYgnqZmbe3///8dk7xKi1KDTIxNdR2UVQA)</s> 

Initial (wrong) solutions: <s>[56](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUPDOlNb20ZF2dBaU7OgKDOvJE0hJkYlOlpZ2SJWw8xUW0NZWaXaMDoztlbX1EhT1chMM/b///9@/uEerkGuAA)</s>, <s>[83b](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIUJBQ6Vao9jKStOwVrM6OlpBJULBtk4h2lE3KlYhNlZNraAoM68kTSEmRiU6WlnZIlbDzFRbQ1lZJULX1EhT1chMM7amBqpGJaL2////fv7hHq5BrlpxFZVViUnJuXn5AA)</s></sub>

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 144

- Input: A1 (Given named range "A", +1 score)
- Column B: `=ArrayFormula(CODE(MID(A,SEQUENCE(LEN(A)),1`, given named range "B", +1 score
- Final output: `=ArrayFormula(JOIN(,IF(B=0,,CHAR(IF((B>64)*(B<91),B+13*-1^(B>77),IF((B<97)+(B>122),B,B+13*-1^(B>109`

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 77 bytes

```hs
r(a:b:c)=[a..b]++r c
main=interact$map$(r"\0@NZAM[`nzam{\1114111"!!).fromEnum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0gj0SrJKlnTNjpRTy8pVlu7SCGZKzcxM882M68ktSgxuUQlN7FARaNIKcbAwS/K0Tc6Ia8qMbc6xtDQ0ASIlRQVNfXSivJzXfNKc///r9NQ8gCam6@jUJ5flJOiqODo5JyYlGxgaPSoaY2SZh0A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
:3
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3A3&i=hello-world)

:3

Answer (score 0):

## [Assembly (MIPS, SPIM)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spim), 122 bytes

```bash
main:li$2 12
syscall
abs$4 $2
and$2 95
sub$2'A'
bgtu$2 25p
sub$4 13
bge$2 13p
add$4 26
p:li$2 11
syscall
bne$4 10main
j$ra
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY09DsIwDIV3n8JDpG6Ipi0SbKgD53CIKUFpGtVUiNMHByHG970/yWEuZaaQTjEYi60FecuVYgRyYno0Fih5dY4DyOaMbc4NuOm5KbJD/rIe204Z136XgbxXZA@Qf5vtf9Mlrul9PYSHWamUcfGMlyXeUH9QVUgTjndNc5pYMAjSi2WZeQcf)

Input is a single line from stdin, output is printed to stdout.

Pretty similar to the other ASM versions as that is the best way on baremetal.

```bash
main:
.Lloop:
    li    $v0, 12            # READ CHARACTER
    syscall                  # v0 = getchar() or '\n'
    abs    $a0, $v0          # Save copy to a0 (abs is shorter than move for positive)
    and    $v0, 0x5F         # Clear bit 6 to convert lowercase to uppercase
    sub    $v0, 'A'          # Try to convert to number.
    bgtu   $v0, 25, .Lprint  # Non-letters will be < 0 or > 25, test with unsigned > 25
    sub    $a0, 13           # Subtract 13 to rotate left
    bge    $v0, 13, .Lprint  # If the letter-to-number was < 13...
    add    $a0, 26           # Add 26 to revert the left rotation and rotate right
.Lprint:
    li     $v0, 11           # 11 = PRINT CHARACTER
    syscall                  # putchar(a0)
    bne    $a0, '\n', .Lloop # Loop if not end of line
    j      $ra               # Return from main
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 2 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 1.65 bytes

```
ZY
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLoiIhDCh_wTrf_BSFxKTS4lRFQ0VFQ4goAA)

Builtins FTW!

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 byte

```
V
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWC8OWFCclF0N5C9Z6pObk5OsohOcX5aQoQgQB)

Built-in solution.

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
kĠD½13ȷẒJsdṆ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWm7OPLHA5tNfQ-MT2h7smeRWnPNzZtqQ4KbkYKr9grUdqTk6-jkJ4flFOiiJEEAA)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ıÐA?Ä12+26%97+Csfh?R
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuhbbj2w8PMHR_nCLoZG2kZmqpbm2c3Fahn3QkuKk5GKomgVrPVJzcvJ1FMLzi3JSFCGCAA)

Non built-in solutions.

##### Explanations

```python
kĠD½13ȷẒJsdṆ  # Implicit input
kĠD           # Push the string [A-Za-z] and duplicate
   ½          # Halve it to yield [[A-Z], [a-z]]
      ȷ       # To each string in the pair:
    13 Ẓ      #  Rotate it 13 places to the right
              # (We now have [[N-ZA-M], [n-za-m]])
        J     # Join it into [N-ZA-Mn-za-m]
         sd   # Swap and cast to a list of characters
           Ṇ  # Transliterate the input string
              # Implicit output
```

```python
ıÐA?Ä12+26%97+Csfh?R  # Implicit input
ı                     # Map over the input string:
 Ð                    #  Triplicate the current character
  A                   #  Pop one copy and check if it's alphabetic
   ?                  #  If it is:
    Ä                 #   Pop another copy and push its 1-based index in the alphabet
     12+              #   Add 12 to this number
        26%           #   Mod this number by 26
           97+        #   Add 97 to this number
              C       #   And convert it to a character
               s      #   Swap so the loop character is back on top
                fh    #   Pop it and check if it's uppercase
                  ?   #   If it is:
                   R  #    Uppercase the character on the top of the stack
                      #   Otherwise, the lowercase character stays on top
                      #  Otherwise, the loop character stays on top
                      # Implicit output, joined
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python + `Rot13`, 23 Bytes

```python
from Rot13 import*
func
```

There is a package dedicated to this, but looking at the source code of the package, it is not well written...