# Find prime factors

Tags: code-golf, primes

A whole program to find the prime factors of a given number. The number will be given on standard input.

Comment: Should we make a function or a whole program? Any time constraints or limit to the input number?

Comment: given number? from STDIN I presume?

Comment: @dogbert yes, from STDIN

Comment: Output format? Space-separated, comma-separaed, each factor on a line? Sorted? With exponents?

Comment: space is fine for output, sorted wasn't specified and I wasn't thinking exponents would be used. just full number.

Answer (score 6):

### Bash Shell

**6 Chars**

`factor`

If `rot13` can be [allowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4/rot-13-transform-standard-input/92#92), i don't see why this one is an issue...I'm sorry but this is very trivial.

Comment: You could argue that this one is more permissible than `rot13`, as this one is part of coreutils which is completely standard, and `rot13` is part of... bsdgames?

Comment: @Nabb: what? are you suggesting `bsdgames` is non-standard? I even have them on my DS (using DSLinux).

Answer (score 6):

### J - 2 characters

```
q:
```

Example:

```
   q: 31415
5 61 103
```

Answer (score 5):

### dc, 48 chars

```
[ldp0<x]sp?2sd[[dsrld~0=p]dsxxcld1+sdlrd1<y]dsyx
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby - <strike>50</strike> <strike>49</strike> <strike>47</strike> <strike>44</strike> 42 chars

```
2.upto(n=gets.to_i){|i|n/=p i while n%i<1}
```

Comment: the `()` for `n=gets.to_i` are superfluous...

Comment: @st0le, ah thanks, made the change.

Comment: In general, `map` is 1 character shorter than `each`. ;) But in this case, you can just use `2.upto(n=gets.to_i)` to save 2 characters.

Comment: [Crossed out 44 is still 44](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7427/58826)

Answer (score 3):

### Python: 58

```
n=input()
for i in range(2,n+1):
 while n%i<1:print i;n/=i
```

Comment: how about `n%i<1`?

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 42 chars

```
map{$n/=$_,print$_,$/until$n%$_}2..($n=<>)
```

Comment: Using `say` instead of `print$_` let you save 4 chars.

Answer (score 3):

### Windows PowerShell, 46

Naïve solution.

```
2..($x=+"$input")|%{for(;!($x%$_)){$_;$x/=$_}}
```

Comment: 43 bytes: `param($x)2..$x|%{for(;!($x%$_)){$_;$x/=$_}}`

Comment: The number is given on standard input. Read the task first, please.

Comment: parm($x) is pure way to declare a standard input. Read the Powershell documentation first, please :)

Comment: Try it out for yourself: `echo 35 | powershell -noprofile -command "param($x)2..$x|%{for(;!($x%$_)){$_;$x/=$_}}"`. `param` declares a parameter to a function/script/scriptblock which is given after the invocation, not as pipeline input. Standard input is a well-defined term and refers to one of the default streams available to console programs on many platforms.

Comment: You don't need to run a PowerShell script as command from cmd.exe. Save the text to a file (test.ps1, for example) and run it from Powershell `PS> test.ps1 35` :)

Comment: To run a script text (not script file) with paramters you need to use a powershell call operator `&`. For example `& {param($x)2..$x|%{for(;!($x%$_)){$_;$x/=$_}}} 35`. If you insist on running a powershell scriptblock from `cmd.exe` then try `powershell -noprofile -command "& {param($x)2..$x|%{for(;!($x%$_)){$_;$x/=$_}}} 35"`.

Comment: `$input` is one of several [automatic variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables). You do not have to use only it. There are other ways :)

Comment: @mazzy: The point is, that a command-line argument to the script/scriptblock/function is *not* standard input.

Comment: (oO) as you wish

Answer (score 2):

### Python (55)

based on marcog

```
n=input()
i=1
while~-n:
 i+=1
 while n%i<1:print i;n/=i
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pure Bash Solution (60 characters)

Based on [F.Hauri](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9424)'s [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/667/find-prime-factors/13026#13026) (thanks to him):

```
read p;for((i=2;p-1;));do((p%i++||(p/=--i)*0))||echo $i;done
```

Comment: `*0` great idea!

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript (54)

```
n=prompt()*1;for(i=2;n>1;n/=n%i?(++i,1):(alert(i),i));
```

Comment: You can do `prompt()*1` instead of `parseInt(prompt())` to convert to an integer.

Comment: `+prompt()` is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

### C (68)

Not the shortest, but I was curious to see how a C solution could compare.

```
d=2;main(n){scanf("%d",&n);for(;n>1;)n%d?++d:printf("%d\n",d,n/=d);}
```

Comment: Nice. You can also take advantage of the fact that `printf` accepts a variable number of arguments to hide the `n/=d` in its argument list. I suspect you could also save a character or two by promoting `d` to a global variable.

Comment: Good ideas! That brings it to 68.

Answer (score 1):

### 100% Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash): 72 chars

```
read p;for((i=1;p>i++;));do while((p%i<1));do echo $i;((p/=i));done;done
```

or

```
read p;i=1;while((p>i++));do while((p%i<1));do o+=$i\ ;((p/=i));done;done ;echo $o
```

This seem longer, but in replacing `for` by `while`, I could make an overall loop and using `alias` to reduce then code:

```
alias D=done W=while
prime() { W read p;do i=1 o=;W((p>i++));do W((p%i<1));do o+=$i\ ;((p/=i));D;D;echo $o;D;}
unalias D W
```

This way, my (written) code **whith** the loop is 77 char length.

Anyway, the function is memorized with full command names:

```
declare -f prime
prime () 
{ 
    while read p; do
        i=1 o=;
        while ((p>i++)); do
            while ((p%i<1)); do
                o+=$i\ ;
                ((p/=i));
            done;
        done;
        echo $o;
    done
}
```

Comment: Hi @F.Hauri `:)`. Here's a shorter version: `read p;for((i=2;p-1;));do((p%i==0&&(p/=i)))&&echo $i||((++i));done`. Also, use `declare -f prime` instead of the ugly `set | sed`. Cheers `:)`.

Comment: Even shorter: `read p;for((i=2;p-1;));do((p%i&&++i))||{((p/=i));echo $i;};done` (63 chars `:)`).

Comment: Hi @gniourf_gniourf, thanks for `declare -f`, sometime, re-reading man pages... Bravo for your shortest bash solution, if you publish I will upvote!

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 26 chars

```
#&@@@FactorInteger@Input[]
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 72 characters

Just for the kicks, an attempt without using any preexisting function to prime-factorize:

```
n=scan(n=1);m=1:n;M=m[!n%%m&!m%in%c(1,n)];M[rowSums(!outer(M,M,`%%`))<2]
```

Ungolfed with explanations:

```r
n <- scan(n=1) #Take one number from stdin
m <- 1:n
#Of which of the integers from 1 to n is n a multiple (excluding 1 and himself):
M <- m[!n%%m & !m%in%c(1,n)] 
#Trim that list by excluding integers that are multiples of others in the list:
M[rowSums(!outer(M,M,`%%`))<2]
```

NB: Instead of checking if `n%%m==0`, use the fact the `0` coerce as `FALSE` when using `!`.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 111 bytes:

```
def f(i:Int,c:Int=2):List[Int]=if(i==c)List(i)else
if(i%c==0)c::f(i/c,c)else f(i,c+1)
f(readInt).mkString(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

### perl5.10:  36 chars

```
map{$p/=$_,say until$p%$_}2..($p=<>)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell 74 chars

```
s n=f((==0).mod n)[2..n]
main=readLn>>=print.f((==1).length.s).s
f=filter
```

### Example

```
12 -> [2,3]
128 -> [2]
60 -> [2,3,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, 17 chars

```
factor(input(''))
```