# Return prime factorization of a number

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

Yes, this is old and probably very simple, but I really want to be mindblown by things that I thought were obvious, so here's the **challenge**:

You're given a positive integer as the input and you need to output the **exponents** of all of the prime factors **up to the highest factor** in base 36 ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, b, c ... z ). If there are some primes in between that are no factors, they have exponent 0. The output must be ordered can be either an array or a string separated by `\n`,  (space) or just outputs from different calls. The program should calculate correctly the output for exponents bigger than 36, but it's not required

Say you're given `42` as the input, its prime factorization is `2*3*7`, all of which have `1` as the exponent, but there is also `5` with an exponent of `0`, so your output would be `[ 1, 1, 0, 1 ]` because `2` is the first prime and has an exponent of `1`, `3` is the second and has an exponent of `1`, `5` is the third and has an exponent of `0` and so on. Here are the correct input/outputs for the first 30 numbers

```
2   1
3   0 1
4   2
5   0 0 1
6   1 1
7   0 0 0 1
8   3
9   0 2
10  1 0 1
11  0 0 0 0 1
12  2 1
13  0 0 0 0 0 1
14  1 0 0 1
15  0 1 1
16  4
17  0 0 0 0 0 0 1
18  1 2
19  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
20  2 0 1
21  0 1 0 1
22  1 0 0 0 1
23  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
24  3 1
25  0 0 2
26  1 0 0 0 0 1
27  0 3
28  2 0 0 1
29  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
30  1 1 1
```

and you can find a working expanded version of this [on codepen](http://codepen.io/towc/pen/Qjjzmx)

The solution with the lowest number of bytes wins. Feel free to send in languages who have built-in prime factorization functions, but I won't accept them as answers for pretty obvious reasons. If you send in a solution that doesn't use such functions I'll consider it. It's kind of a grey area, but we'll figure it out.

#### Edit:

If it's unclear what do I mean by "base", consider the number `3072`. Its prime factors are `2` and `3`. `2` has an exponent of `10`, so in base 36 that's `a`. That means that the output would look like this:

```
a 1
```

or the number `732421875000` whose factorization is `2^3 * 3^1 * 5^15`, whose output would be

```
3 1 f
```

Comment: Huh, where does base 36 come in?

Comment: @xnor it's what most languages support. I use JS as a baseline, and number.toString( base ) only works on a base up to 36 for example. Not really important, but again, you can use any base above 36 if you wish, it's not required for it to work after that :)

Comment: I still don't understand. What base?

Comment: @xnor number base. Ya know, binary, ternary, octal, decimal, hexadecimal,  7, 9, **36**, 42, 34123432

Comment: What he's asking is what part of the challenge requires output in base 36?

Comment: For example, input `1024` should be output `a`, right?

Comment: I'd the output is to be base 36, that's totally arbitrary. It's trivial for languages with a built-in and annoyingly tangential otherwise.

Comment: downvoted for requiring base 36. if it's meant to be a twist, it isn't very interesting. also, for what xnor said

Comment: would base 16 be better? @xnor I agree with the fact that it may be a problem for a few languages

Comment: but 16 would be pretty short to implement, right?

Comment: @towc It would be the same, either there's a builtin or not. I don't see the reason for the twist.

Comment: Also, this might be a dupe of an existing factorization challenge. I wouldn't count just giving exponents or using a base as much different. Could someone please check existing challenges?

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1979/20469) (@xnor – Is this the dupe you had in mind?)

Comment: @AlexA. Oh, nice, hadn't seen it

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 51 bytes

```
@(n)dec2base(histc(factor(n),unique(factor(n))),36)
```

This defines an anonymous function that takes a number and returns a char array. Explanation to come.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 15 bytes

```
VheSPQIP_NC/PQN
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VheSPQIP_NC%2FPQN&input=1583817601203918457031250000000000&debug=0)

Outputs in base 256.

(Base36 version, 33 bytes)

```
VheSPQIP_NjjkmC++48d*>hdT7j/PQN36
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VheSPQIP_NjjkmC%2B%2B48d*%3CdT7j%2FPQN36&input=1583817601203918457031250000000000&debug=0)

(Base 10 version, 14 bytes)

```
VheSPQIP_N/PQN
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VheSPQIP_NC%2FPQN&input=1583817601203918457031250000000000&debug=0)

All versions are separated by newlines. There is some unclearness over whether not base 36 outputs are allowed so I included many versions. Uses factorisation functions and is_prime functions.

Comment: any base above 36 would have been fine :)

Comment: Base 256 isn't particularly readable though.

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 80 bytes

```
#~IntegerExponent~Prime@Range@PrimePi@FactorInteger[#][[-1,1]]~IntegerString~36&
```

I tried. Without factorization:

### Mathematica, 90 bytes

```
#~IntegerExponent~Prime@Range@PrimePi@Select[Divisors@#,PrimeQ][[-1,1]]~IntegerString~36&
```