# Calculate the prime factors

Tags: code-golf, primes, factoring

We had a [prime factorization challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1979/42545) a while ago, but that challenge is nearly six years old and barely meets our current requirements, so I believe it's time for a new one.

### Challenge

Write a program or function that takes as input an integer greater than 1 and outputs or returns a list of its prime factors.

### Rules

- Input and output may be given by any standard method and in any standard format.
- Duplicate factors must be included in the output.
- The output may be in any order.
- The input will not be less than 2 or more than 2<sup>31</sup> - 1.
- Built-ins are allowed, but including a non-builtin solution is encouraged.

### Test cases

```
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
4 -> 2, 2
6 -> 2, 3
8 -> 2, 2, 2
12 -> 2, 2, 3
255 -> 3, 5, 17
256 -> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
1001 -> 7, 11, 13
223092870 -> 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23
2147483646 -> 2, 3, 3, 7, 11, 31, 151, 331
2147483647 -> 2147483647
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **the shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: Would've been much better if you disallowed built-ins.

Comment: @TheBitByte Challenges that disallow built-ins are generally looked down upon as [Do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/42545) challenges, especially since it's sometimes hard to tell whether a solution is technically a built-in.

Comment: Well then, enjoy the influx of <5 byte solutions! As I write this, Pyth already does it in 1 byte.

Comment: @TheBitByte Think of it as a language-by-language challenge, primarily. Try to beat Python's solution, or some other language without a builtin.

Comment: @isaacg Well, language-by-language is a better way of looking at it, I agree.

Comment: I can't seem to find the "standard format" meta post. Are trailing separators allowed? i.e. Input `4`, Output `2,2,`?

Comment: @BrianJ I don't know that we have one. I'll allow that for this challenge.

Comment: Why do you mark my question as a duplicate of yours when your question is clearly the duplicate as it has been posted later? Please rectify this decision.

Comment: @FUZxxl It's the [community consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8286/42545) that old questions should be closed as duplicates of newer ones if the newer one has a very clear spec. The main reasons for this are that old challenges tend not to be up-to-date with today's challenge specs, and newer languages can participate in newer challenges. However, as the output format is quite different for your challenge, I've reopened it.

Comment: @ETHproductions So is my spec not very clear? Can you explain where it is unclear? You should avoid conflicts-of-interest like these where you use your permissions to close another users question over yours.

Comment: @FUZxxl After talking with other users, I've decided that closing your question was not the action I should have taken. It would have been better to let the community decide whether your spec is clear enough, and thus whether or not to close it. I apologize for the ruckus I've caused.

Comment: Can the code exit with an error?

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=2:n/k*[0]and(f(n,k+1),[k]+f(n/k,k))[n%k<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqJCnk21rZJWnn60VbRCbmJeikaYBFNI21NSJzo7VBnL0s3WyNTWj81SzbQxj/xcUZeaVKKRpGJmaav4HAA)

Comment: I'd bet you've had this waiting for most of an hour...

Answer (score 15):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=P&input=2147483646&debug=0), 1 byte

```
P
```

I like Pyth's chances in this challenge.

Comment: Until the "P" language comes along and does it in 0 bytes

Answer (score 11):

### Python 2, 53 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=2:n/i*[f]and[f(n,i+1),[i]+f(n/i)][n%i<1]
```

Tries each potential divisor `i` in turn. If `i` is a divisor, prepends it and restarts with `n/i`. Else, tries the next-highest divisor. Because divisors are checked in increasing order, only the prime ones are found.

As a program, for 55 bytes:

```python
n=input();i=2
while~-n:
 if n%i:i+=1
 else:n/=i;print i
```

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, <s>38</s> 30 bytes

Thanks @MartinEnder for 8 bytes!

```
Join@@Table@@@FactorInteger@#&
```

Comment: How about `FactorInteger[#][[All, 1]]&`?  **26 bytes**

Comment: @DavidG.Stork that wouldn't work because it would not repeat the prime factors if the power is greater than 1.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 48 bytes

```hs
(2%)
n%1=[]
n%m|mod m n<1=n:n%div m n|k<-n+1=k%m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BbsIwDIbvfgofqMREI9Vx2xREuPACHCdtHKpBt6pNmMa0C@zVlznVaNEkW/Zvf7/9Vp@7Y9@Hxj6HuU4ewCdkn/ZS3NWdDujQr8n6lU8O7VdU126t/IJsl7jg6tajxfeP1n/iDBukLCOAiwKNaoMaOBaGfFCpDMq/jqG6zeKY9KQYdFEMvhSLFMmILu/gfwHxZ1wbYUlS/Jqzpa5Mdns2HBr38abkUszCUm7yisu8nGAeYY6GIjZME2oGdFSgvsPPS9PXr@egHre73S8) Example usage: `(2%) 1001` yields `[7,11,13]`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Æf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@4Le3/4fZHTWvc//830lEw1lEw0VEw01Gw0FEwBPKNTE1BBFDA0MDAEMg0MjawNLIwNwAyDU3MTSyMzUzMkNjmAA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 44 bytes

```
f=(n,x=2)=>n-1?n%x?f(n,x+1):[x,...f(n/x)]:[]
```

Horribly inefficient due to the fact that it iterates from 2 up to every prime factor, including the last. You can cut the time complexity dramatically at the cost of 5 bytes:

```
f=(n,x=2)=>x*x>n?[n]:n%x?f(n,x+1):[x,...f(n/x,x)]
```

Comment: You can save a byte by outputting a string rather than an array: `f=(n,i=2)=>n%i?n-1?f(n,i+1):"":i+" "+f(n/i)`

Comment: @Spitemaster Another byte (use comma): `f=(n,i=2)=>n%i?f(n,i+1):n-i?i+[,f(n/i)]:i`

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), <s>37</s> 32 bytes

```
vs(...<..1I>(!@)s)%?w;O,s(No;^;<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#@19WrKGnp2ejp2foaaeh6KBZrKlqX27tr1Os4ZdvHWdt8/@/kZGxgaWRhbkBAA) or [Watch it in action](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=dnMoLi4uPC4uMUk+KCFAKXMpJT93O08scyhObzteOzw=&input=MTI=&speed=4).

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 47 bytes

Basically this checks all integers `2, 3, 4, 5, ...` for divisors of `n`. If we find one, we factor that out and repeat the process until we get to `1`.

```hs
f 1=[]
f n=(:)<*>f.div n$until((<1).mod n)(+1)2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BDoIwDIbvfYoeOIACoSswMMCLGA8kSFyEaRS9GJ8dNyJgTNas/9/v73aq7@dj141ji1TuD9CiLt2dV2yqNmzUE7Xz0IPqXLcgL@wvDWrP3ZInxr5WGku83pQe0MEWheAoF5mMAF4BCAwqFMD2Yogn5Rsj/XYM2exZm8SqGESSTDkfEx9JGp3@wH8HKIrIjqVhyZTJz1@ZH5sWLXO701RuwoalWMYZp3G6wrzAbAOJbZhWVE7ooiB4jx8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 6 bytes

```
w`in`M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@1@ekJmX4Pv/vwUA)

Explanation:

```
w`in`M
w       factor into primes and exponents
 `in`M  repeat each prime # of times equal to exponent
```

Comment: You can probably just use `o` now, right?

Comment: @Oliver Yes, but I don't usually update old answers with builtins.

Answer (score 3):

## J, 2 bytes

```
q:
```

<s>Body must be at least 30 characters.</s>

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
Yf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x@Z9v@/kQkA)

Obligatory "boring built-in answer".

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 2 bytes

```
Uk
```

A built-in `k` used on the input `U`. Also refers to a country.

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=VWs=&input=MTEwMTE=)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
ǐ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLHkCIsIiIsIjIxNDc0ODM2NDYiXQ==)

Just the built-in. But that's boring, so

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>16</s> 8 bytes

```
K~æ~Ǒ$ẋf
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJLfsOmfseRJOG6i2YiLCIiLCIyMTQ3NDgzNjQ2Il0=)

### Explained

```
ʀ~æ~Ǒ$ẋf
ʀ~æ      # From the all numbers in the range [0, input], keep only those that are prime
   ~Ǒ    # Without popping anything, get the multiplicity of each prime divisor - this leaves the stack as [divisors, multiplicities]
     $ẋ  # Swap the two items and repeat each divisor multiplicity times
       f # Flatten and output that
```

Comment: I think you should keep the 16 byte version too, since that doesn't even use any built-ins for enumerating divisors. (Though maybe there's something between 8 and 16 bytes that also fits that criterion.)

Comment: @Deadcode I'll be honest, i only removed it because I didn't think it would work anymore - it was written a very long time ago and many things have changed since. But turns out it still works in older versions, so I'll put it back a little later.

Answer (score 2):

## [tone-deaf](https://github.com/kade-robertson/tone-deaf), 3 bytes

This language is quite young and not really ready for anything major yet, but it can do prime factorization:

```
A/D
```

This will wait for user input, and then output the list of prime factors.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 6 bytes

I think this does not require any explanation.

```
factor
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 96 bytes

```
@set/an=%1,f=2,r=0
:l
@set/af+=!!r,r=n%%f
@if %r%==0 echo %f%&set/an/=f
@if %n% gtr 1 goto l
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```r
p=function(n,i=2)if(n>1)c(i[m<-!n%%i],p(n/i^m,i+!m))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHxCoIwEMb/7ykuIthoktvUGWQvEhVhEw5yytTnt1liOQnuYPvuft/dmO1ri6W@Ffe8rWyT9XVWdCZvsTLEMMwExYKYE6c5wXN5DNZmu8ULq4nZ47VkuFuXlM49iKCwgeAkVnNZfmTpydHYzcAHkqniM@mXWWJc/FZ9VMTxuAeDmAFXi3oyM/fCnxWG/NOunBd3uZgnZHgQqQq/j3kPnvqHHVwenPmC5ZGKUplEyS8sJ1gOBvFwkPwfqkZ0ukMGxR2fDTw6DW3logoeWtdgdd7Zxn38qn8B)

Recursive function: overflows the stack limit and errors on TIO for the last test case.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```r
function(n,i=2)while(n>1)if(n%%i)i=i+1 else{show(i);n=n/i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/taoMwFIb/9yoOlIJhlplEjWWktzJcG9dDs2QkEX@MXbvTVmyNDHLgfD3ve@L6b4df6r2pT8E6L/umNaeA1iQmRclId0GtEnOkBJvE7HZIUOILBaW9@vEX2yVI3ow0r/i7VEoYgS3sj2yzbPN7m0ftfNpOIQbKeRIz1YNZY5Q9T2OUFcV0RwpFClSs5uVCPHqxV5bR@7oYtOgQKz/GswOrRPb4zM143h9vGOIwiK9Ymou84mVePsN8hvkoUIwJp5vtP6yY2LkGCWerPBgbQDlnXQofbYAOtYZQXxXUoK35hDDIQW3O4O0t93vbhv4P)

Non-recursive function: does not error for large primes, but will still take a very long time to run (and so times-out without erroring on TIO for the last test case anyway).

Answer (score 2):

## [CellTail](https://github.com/mousetail/CellTail/blob/main/README.md), 166 bytes

```
N,(u,u,_),N:1,(u,1),(0,2);(0,2),N,N:1,N,N;N,(u,v,0),N:1,(v,1),(u/v,2,(u/v)%2);N,(u,v,w),N:1,(u,v+1,u%(v+1)),N;a&(_,_,_),N,N:1,a,N;_,(v,1),_:1,v,N;N,u,N:1,(u,2,u%2),N;
```

[Try the demo](https://mousetail.github.io/CellTail/#ST1DIE47Ck89TjsKI009NDA7CgpOLCh1LHUsXyksTjoxLCh1LDEpLCgwLDIpOygwLDIpLE4sTjoxLE4sTjtOLCh1LHYsMCksTjoxLCh2LDEpLCh1L3YsMiwodS92KSUyKTtOLCh1LHYsdyksTjoxLCh1LHYrMSx1JSh2KzEpKSxOO2EmKF8sXyxfKSxOLE46MSxhLE47XywodiwxKSxfOjEsdixOO04sdSxOOjEsKHUsMix1JTIpLE47)

### Explanation:

Base case, when we reach the end switch to a recursion resistant tuple and pass a message right to break it. Then the message right sends a 1 to prevent recursion when the tuple has broken.

```
N,(u,u,_),N:1,(u,1),(0,2);(0,2),N,N:1,N,N;
```

We have found a factor, try again in the cell to the right with `(u/v)`

```
N,(u,v,0),N:1,(v,1),(u/v,2,(u/v)%2);
```

We have not found a factor, try another.

```
N,(u,v,w),N:1,(u,v+1,u%(v+1)),N;
```

Copy 3-tuples from left to current

```
a&(_,_,_),N,N:1,a,N;
```

Break recursion resistant tuples. Hopefully the next step the value from the right will throw a 1 to break the recursion.

```
_,(v,1),_:1,v,N;
```

Base case, start with trying 2 as a factor.

```
N,u,N:1,(u,2,u%2),N;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 19 bytes

```bash
factor|sed s/.*:.//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@WmFySX1RTnJqiUKyvp2Wlp6///7@RqSkA)

Comment: You can shave off a byte if whitespace doesn't matter in the output using `factor|sed s/.*://`. Also `factor|cut -d: -f2` (or `factor|cut -d\  -f2` to match your current output) is the same byte length but is going to run faster and use less memory overhead.

Comment: I'll ask the OP about whitespace. Sadly, I'd need `factor|cut -d\ -f2-` to eliminate the leading space, which is one byte longer.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 1 byte

```
P
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=P&input=12)

Prime factors builtin.

Answer (score 1):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 58 bytes

Not done golfing yet, but @MartinEnder should be able to destroy this anyway

Prints out factors space-separated, with a trailing space

Golfed:

```
2}\..}$?i6;>(<...=.\'/})."@...>%<..'':\}$"!>~\{=\)=\}&<.\\
```

Laid-out:

```
     2 } \ . .
    } $ ? i 6 ;
   > ( < . . . =
  . \ ' / } ) . "
 @ . . . > % < . .
  ' ' : \ } $ " !
   > ~ \ { = \ )
    = \ } & < .
     \ \ . . .
```

Explanation coming later.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
Ò
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3940v//RoYm5iYWxmYmZgA)

Comment: I wonder how many people will outgolf Dennis...

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 2 bytes

```
mf
```

[cjam.aditsu.net/...](//cjam.aditsu.net#code=rimf%60&input=2147483646)

This is a function. Martin, it seems I was sleepy.

Answer (score 1):

### C, 92 bytes

```
int p(int n){for(int i=2;i<n;i++)if(n%i==0)return printf("%d, ",i)+p(n/i);printf("%d\n",n);}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int prime(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            printf("%d, ", i);
            return prime(number / i); //you can golf away a few bytes by returning the sum of your recursive function and the return of printf, which is an int
        }                             //this allow you to golf a few more bytes thanks to inline calls
    }
    printf("%d\n", number);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    prime(atoi(argv[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1 byte

```
k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5/9/7@RkbGBpZGFuYECAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 259 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;interface g{static void main(String[]z){int a=new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();int b=0;int[]l={};for(int i=2;i<=a;i++){for(;a%i<1;l[b-1]=i){l=Arrays.copyOf(l,b=l.length+1);a/=i;}}for(int i=0;i<b;i++)System.out.print(l[i]+(i<b-1?", ":""));}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#RY5BT4QwEIX/SkNi0sputStZzZbGePTkgSPhMGDB2ZRCyuwqEn47gjHx9JL33nzzFmz7LhA7wxXkhdDJW42ebKihsqyZBgLCil07fGctoOcZBfRNXnyLae0xMN5@sqwC723g2TiQbSV6Ib39oldPXGw4Vpr7TfPCmWnWdRf45qI5aEwNaIxjMW2uhhtMlXZ5uVeFQTE58xICjIOsun58q7nblcZJZ31DH7ESGu4M6nn@J65/0vIX@Demu5Ds183EXY5FzNd4r56jHYtOUSTEerwsB5U8Jk8Px@T4Aw)

Comment: Refer to this gist to see how this submission can be golfed further: https://gist.github.com/kritixilithos/fde37dc5a8ae54852aa134a6e70ea495. If you need to clarify something, feel free to ping me at the 19th byte :)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 51 bytes

```php
for($i=2;1<$a=&$argn;)$a%$i?$i++:$a/=$i*print"$i ";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkbGysZP0/Lb9IQyXT1sja0EYl0VYNLGetqZKoqpJpr5KprW2lkqhvq5KpVVCUmVeipJKpANTzHwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>48</s> 45 bytes

```ruby
->x{r,*c=2;0while x%r>0?x>=r+=1:c<<r&&x/=r;c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iukhHK9nWyNqgPCMzJ1WhQrXIzsC@ws62SNvW0CrZxqZITa1C37bIOrn2v4ahnp6pqaZebmJBdU1FTYFCdIWOQlp0RWxs7X8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 51 bytes

```c
i;f(n){for(i=2;i<=n;)n%i?i++:printf("%d ",i,n/=i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7LCsIwEEXX5itKoDClLSZp@tBY/RapNMzCWGpdlX57TEwEcXXuXM4MM5R6GKxFNYLJ1vExA/ZC4ak3KjMpXjDPj9OMZhmBpreEFliYfY@Z2qwGVycmIyvZ/Sjl2VmuVmTnbzpMr@UJlLq4EeJ37lc08NnTILyhoQqQAU1AF8CjI@r6G6LAGeOxEhU7iK5lceSylV3VyOZvbv0X9g0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 1 [byte](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
ḋ
```

Boring built-in answer

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//4Y7u//8NjY0B)

Comment: Unfortunately, the non-built-in solution doesn't work on any number containing a duplicate factor (e.g. `8`)

Comment: Yep, you're right. Lemme delete it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 19 bytes

```
IT1WP2K%ZB|:N,:M?t;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1NCgIxDIX3PUU37io0Sf9mBhTciSguBMEDqAOCi3Hp3WtSnFaEhua9fC@5PR/XcbrnvD3B@Yi7xWXz7g@m369fQ0a9XGlUJB8pV5RhI3w7Umn2xAZsihR6X3JGe6Mhsg4/8N9TYC3IODILXJxHsh2maOdjZVGdy06ujsPMgosuUXChwVRhkoCXhqChsaBV5XrvAw)

### Explanation

```
IT                  < [n]     read input to n then mark cell (T)
  1WP     |         < [n m=2] from 2 onwards (m=1;while m:m++;)
     2K%ZB          < [n m+1] copy two elements, mod, break if n%m==0
           :N       < [n m] (< where n%m==0) print m with newline
             ,:M?t; < [n/m] (< new n)        divide, if not 1 redo from T else exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 1 char, 2 bytes

```
π
```

That is...

Comment: ... rather short?

Comment: @JonathanFrech yes it is short... Less than a character should be impossible...

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 47 bytes

```hs
f 1=[]
f n=[k:f a|k<-[2..],a<-[1..n],a*k==n]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03B0DY6litNIc82OtsqTSGxJttGN9pITy9WJxHIMNTTywOytLJtbfNiFRUN/ucmZuYp2CoUFGXmlSioKKQpGJma/gcA)

```hs
f 1=[]
f n=[k:f(div n k)|k<-[2..],mod n k<1]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03B0DY6litNIc82OtsqTSMls0whTyFbsybbRjfaSE8vVic3PwUkYmMYq6ho8D83MTNPwVahoCgzr0RBRSFNwcjU9D8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Regex (ECMAScript or better), 28 bytes

```
(?=(xx+?)\1*$)(x+)\2*(?=\2$)
```

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number. Returns its output as the list of matches' `\1` captures, whose lengths represent the prime factors.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@9bsIwEMf3PkVAiNwRCBhVHUgNUwcWhnYEBoscwa0xkW3ADbD2AfqIfZE0QaB2O/2/dL93cRB2ZWTuejaXKZntTn/QZ2m4pmPwStmLzwEKPu53Sphw8D6a4IJ1Wgg@wsWwU4mLYQvLTr/A2O3enJE6A4ytkiuCp27vEbtBmIWYWD5IjhupCEBxQyJVUhMgNrjeK4WnjKvY5ko6CHtVXK4BNM9iRTpzGxwPz2dpZ2IGkufCWJpqB9l8sES8G/Tf0GM2YaPaRrcxu2Nzqg9CyTQwQmc0CpqRSh7WOwOJfOaUyCjCk223872zzkC40NePWeJ50zdjQzkJBxKTW0BGYfDz9R1UqXqkqNhgy01Mnlbga6grVVJwhqfib7cu3O7tnC3vdDVtY1vR3AUTK2HdVKfko@hyuZSsxwYD9gs) - ECMAScript
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BTsMwEEX3PYVVjWpPkzRxJDY4blKpbFmxI5VVUAqWTBrsIoIis@QAHJGLBDeA2HzN/5r587rGmovx6Y2AFWQwx/u9IZCKYGWx3dxs1n52OFoGTmaiWAsciD4Eh0NndXsi87qdC08qI11n9InRhMbu5c6dwomKEx5zbJ7PS@V/moUcL0GhOHe58HFvK1PkOFTmlu9k0Gwn/IyQ6bP@DUAXcloIUxThAG6xmCAmhgDIxQ8T6BUlXx@fVEAraU970OL1UZuGBf@egk0f/vApoStWRaE0qZKgKLz3Sl1db5UaWSlZ30cl1nwJyPoI63wZwjoHHEee8Czj3w) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZLNbtswDMfveQpWECop8WeOUbxclg4BhnZId6sLwXGU2IstG5JTBChy7QPsEfciGZ20G9bDDtVBkMgfyb8orjJXnBY39wlYna3Bt2tgDOx0ytSHFhtMZ23RArWQAAkJBNBavVVWt1WWa87CYDhTqsiqTuVN3ZaVtilPhUyXoWMeFvdgg0a11T1gOm06x5W6WXydKyU8iAWmxMRyUJpSOd1x0uZWB6ss33UWN1WVddkRD4gfEyHhX8zqfG9d2Zj/Yz8urgg9g01jOS2TSNIq2aAsx@@/f17cCimeodxwWj24zlba4En48WOSkNQQgbDbr9CDZi/y/Fj08frQVs1ac@ITD3GJ8XmzN10fOx1j0AMmwD16lAOAc2Xzeqdmmpz9eBqNBDwjACgA@BWnu@Tc5Trr8kJlVcWp9bB233addZwdmEeN8GgthACqL3SVuU5pa7GKuEqSb8v5F3V7p@bL5d1SvmbHlwudF03/JgnYhlhCfwdqAga/Xn6yC4lSdZYXnNaoEDIH9ElcQAYseGvQk5B/VdMdXF@jmD/cvJcyQfydOlW7LT9HHo/vRgfNJz5L@OEwmok0HlLBDyORjodoTMdUnD42xYOzIt8Aoc92MvHjI/mU478FONpSH3QO4d7ZcFWasB/2N9cp9uMoin8D) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLBbtswDIbveQpWEGoxsRM7xylGLsuGAkM7eLvVheB6SuxFlg1ZKQwUvfYB9oh7kYxO2g7rYQcJEvn95C9CXdUdV@uu6oA7SIEtGMyhc3qnnO5MUWoRLObTtVJVYbwq26arjXa5yFHm2aIPQghobSmodnoErNfW90KpT1dfNkphCAlSSSosJ7WtVa@9YF3p9Py@KPfe0aZM3dSehcCihKGEfzGny4Pr69b@H/t5TsWUmWxbJ3idxpKbdEu2evHt@8era5T4CPVWcHPbe2e0pRNGyV2astwyJLg/3FOGwmEcRgmOej10pv2hBYtYSLgkfdkerB@1qyWJbqkA7fGdnACcOtuXO7er9JSn02yG8EgAkAEQF4Lv09OUm8KXlSqMEdyF1Hscuy68CIYg5BZD3iAicH2mTdF7pZ2jLniRpl@zzWd1faM2WXaTyZfq9HLUZdWOb5JAY0gkjHfgdh7A7@dfwZkkq7ooK8EbcghFD/wBz2AAwfx1QA8o/7rme7i8JDNv3Ga08oHwd@5U0@/ESfn09O7rUPgo1qkYhtka82TKUQwzzJdTCuZLjsdjEiVxnPwB) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNLbtswEN3nFFMhgUl/GCvLKmrQBi1QIEmLZGl7QUuUTYciVXIUKwmy7QF6xF7EHclq0wDWZjQfPs57M9zIBznZ5Pc7XVbOI2zIF9qJYQL/R2rU5mDMq5VqDmYCeiVLcemMURk6H5Kjql4anUFmZAhwLbWFZ@hjASWSeXA6h5Iy7A69tiuQfhVmCw649m4b4HOTqQq1o5NHAF@0UVCkVm27XxaJzOVKUD7iyae6KJRX@a2SufKw7MreBtnfk71bcJ7094YxJtt1i89YSJfEU@ZX2irG@bvU1sZwXbAg1I9amsCi0@FwGHH@/LZ0j8AYHgR4JgT8h0AAp4SwpLr7JIzSwdwOWovJyz728l0iKm/Bp/0fsS2r9oLAE1Jj6ZxR0sJTWhCiSuAuk9YSdW2rGiGFlm0fY3ePAVUptOUJ9Dy7MrGW4UY1SG12EgP0ghjqnTD2RZYqeop9frYAQ@m2SoTKaGTRhIZA9Qh2SpmvFmlVvKikD4ocZmbTBR@DjQ8mhVF2hevzM7iAthLek4kXhJitpZ8tmp5P59l4kcBH7@VjEIU2hjXjQTPoRAEonG@5URupnSZgz1MbkxmNiOC1xGxNCpWE5kW591i3w5YewSWB7zdGbL2sWH9F5qrHb8WttCtFN03HlvOWacGeeC@rI422XqNi7Rh58pSir9uJvKYrUg0LFp3k8PvnLzgJEWkx7tUUG0dPIAKKlbQ5oTYYGKcGK1b6yYcoGpEVK@/qisW814pGxqm37rmx12cn0F3p0A6Uunyh76hd1h27SFnTjC74PB4ec9aM@PxsSMH52THftcu4iyfxdBr/AQ) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPNbptAEL77KaZOVO8abLOJ1AOYREkVtZcqUupDKttCGK9hVVgQu8hOolz7AH3EPkjd2SVxTFuQYGfmm5lvfjapqlGaJPvJ5GTNN0JyuL69/TqL7m4@3dxHX65mHz9HN/ezu6veiZBJ3qw5TFdlqfSk5infjbOquuglWVxDVM2XEMJd/3q7/b46b749PNzPsg/bjOzJZUh2O@eSLtjwlJKdQxdnQ1Quzk7pnv6N77swrMKoclhwlFRgzprHxUVvMkECOSQrkpRSabB0fL@IdZJFNVdNrtW0NRliw4v3UNAnpde@n5SNhukUBvjirxhvs1iPk7jSDToSj45zLlOdERrUHHUSdN3w4LknpIYiFpJQeOoBPtUc6SCYVHTElqEXQIOY87NIQ2kk45Cag82LWCFTVFaNDqx/h7ptJdQcgwWvOmXrAUOw9diUNRAT9vEQNuU6x5GRtjYh3TYDDV5Zmse4SA8nE@tSEAsYJxEyIpS6IJkLVanQ3FpwBdZkMBrQ4BBAMrQazLvwuBrfl0Z5@Z@44Fi8A4yCj8nfYtlNGZp0km9baS6Zw5YBFLxQXBPlwmA3MMSwFwqNprkH/0MTRChNl6ehZAE4jjiu2Fa9AfJIAUmZJGSwkFgSto4FHVhnK4T59OHXj5/97tyUIUyONPS9YTYSy240y67TIjvmSGheY5dqEF6o1HjFU7NJOC1mRI4df5u73YVI8bhOMiI8A3LtFri4IAjDEEaae8ux4hh@7ZCuHB7sG1ErTWmH4j9Fv1wF68OWb/t/8Ho@nNY855oDXnPVmlvTy03BKT3v2Yh5HvudbPI4VftRbouKbE1/AA) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BboMwEEX3nGJkRbIHDLLTHcjKCXICYBEJ01pyB2S8IDlAD9Aj9iLUblp1N3/@/29mvce3hV4O974uIcJ232SwHQQTGGOHuBix79UFB12eUOwVDucyLYfzCY8U6HVb67GDh1HFvATw4Cgzmi1OjtoCvPHNtnoXBasZFpBDlEPhRq9WOIrC92pE@ZwSDCuNqQhuhkcLa8hGKqYTuvuVJPnXxyeXlibDeTYz9vqDtc3saHLRBhEksJ2VhO2zxrm8pmduJDT2eqz/hRr/WIeutVL6Gw) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BbsMgEEX3PsUIRQJsbEG6s4VygpzA9iKScYpExhZmQXKAHiBHzEVcaFp1N3/@/29mvYfPBT92e1sXH2C7b8Kbq4kdeO0JITs7aRZjdeKDKg@cxYoPxzIth@OB7ynQq7ZWYwcPLYt58eDAYsY0W5gstgU47ZptdTYwUhNeQA5hDvkLXg2zGJjr5cjFe0owXimeimBneLSw@mykYjqhul@Jgr6@nlQYnDSl2czY8w82v9/MFicbjGdeAImkRN6@m5SKc/rngkzxXo31v5DjH25XtZJSfQM) - Python (`import regex`)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BasMwEEX3OcXUGCQ5sZC8rBAmkG67KN3FxqSN4gjExMgKUV267QF6xF7EFW7pZmAef94ff315mz1oeDK9iQNHc4Pd9nnLvTkcFVgtFNzO1hlwujdhTOgEbl/KVuuswUwl7vaC87JqFRg8LoCPg7OBkpKwFcDp4gHBYroTLQ@XzlIpGOeL5n9fzPYuFQ7X1LOorJYKBm8xAG4IfH9@AVEwabROAc1iViDj4@sBqWfvvzk6QU2A3BPCNrnkzmAfzpSpScuPvwfTWHXdw@Ou62ZaaxrjumaNLHJG45o1VZFgU@VsnmUphZA/) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BaoQwEIZfJYQBE92IelwJu9Bzn0A9iJ1dAzGRGFF28doH6CP2RWxWaHv8f2a@@Wa0C7qpR613cLJyeMe1OZ8NLuwa7ewi2bomF17nMXC2Jrwu4lDWBfA9up7omx1GpfGD8hIeMitv1mHb9Qw0UYaAMuPs@RNaCVpMo1aeClqqG4M27exsvNCeFK@BREJbZc0WAAyMrJTxzdGUYITG35y/cpKEjUGCS99b3/U4sWiNYjD8ID/4c3HKo@jt5LdglZf/mQhjw29aGSQUDPn@/CLA/qy7w3oI@C69OzuPU7iYajR332@cbtueizzL8h8) - .NET

```
(?=(xx+?)\1*$)  # Assert tail ≥ 2; \1 = the smallest prime factor of tail
(x+)\2*(?=\2$)  # tail = \2 = the largest proper divisor of tail
```

## Regex (.NET), 31 bytes

```
((?=(xx+?)\2*$)(x+)\3*(?=\3$))*
```

Returns its output as the list of captures on the Balancing Group 2 stack, whose lengths represent the prime factors.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BaoQwEIZfJciAiW5E3dtK2IWe@wTqQeysBmISYkTZxWsfoI/YF7Gu0Pb4/cz88401M7qxR6U2cKJ02OFSXy4aZ3oLN0qvgi5LfGVVHgGjS8yqc7SH1RkYi7bwdgrezGClwo@AFfAQaXE3Dpu2p6CI1ASktpNnT2gEKD5aJX3Ag0LeKTRJaybtufIkfw3EApoyrde9gIIWpdS@PpICNFf4y9mL43jfGAS45L3xbY8jDZcwAs2O5gd7zk565L0Z/bpbZcU/E67N/p6SGkkAmnx/fhGgf9btYT0knTOTHcu8TtrG@snhuF9sE4W68/3KgnXdMp6lafYD)

```
(
    (?=(xx+?)\2*$)  # Push the smallest prime factor of tail onto the Group 2
                    # capture stack.
    (x+)\3*(?=\3$)  # tail = \3 = the largest proper divisor of tail
)*                  # Loop the above as many times as possible, minimum zero.
```

This regex naturally handles an input of 1 correctly, returning an empty list.

## Regex (Perl / PCRE / Boost / Ruby), 41 bytes

```
(?=(xx+?)\1*$)(?=(x+)\2+$).*?\K\1(?=\2?$)
```

Returns its output as the list of matches, whose lengths represent the prime factors.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7PSsNAEMbvfYqlDN1M86fZgBc326RQT4Inb6YsVVJdWNOYRIyE9egD@Ii@SDqNipeP@T5mvvnVZWMvxud3Bo1kgz0@7C2DlSSr0u3mdrN2s8Ox8aBVsUzXEgdmDuRwqBtTdWxeVHPpWG5VW1vTeTzkQft633Z0ooNQBALLl/NS9p/GlOMlaJTnrpY@7pvcpgkOub0TO0Ua76SbMTZ9Nr8BmFRNCzT5Pg7QLhYTxMRAgEL@MIGJOPv@/OISKsV73oORb0/Glh75jxU0q8c/fM545OU@1Yd5SIrSOaf11c1W69HLlNf3foaFWAJOzsci8QGjZVZcF4KiIskAx1GEIo7FCQ) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLLbtswELz7KzYEEXEj2ZaEtIVLC7rULYIWSaH2FgWEotKWYOoBigkMBLn2A/qJ/RF3JactkAMX3OXM7OyCfdUf12lf9cAtJMCWDBbQW71TVvemKLXwlouLVKmqME6VXdPXRttc5CjzbDl4AXh0tlRUOz0CWqdbNwilPl592SiFAURIkiQsZ3Vbq0E7wfrS6sV9Ue6dpaBM3dSOBcAu49Xl6u27ePWGoZxtOyt4nYSSm2RL6oP49v3D1TVKfIJ6K7i5HZw1uqUbzqO7JGF5y5DAw8M9vVA5CIN5hCNfH3rT/dCCzVlAcEn8snto3chdx0S6JQGK4Z2cAUyd25ect@tkeqeb7yM8EQDIAIgzwffJtKymcGWlCmMEtwH1HrenCye8gxfwFgPeICJwfUKbYnBKW0td8CxJvmabT@r6Rm2y7CaTL@o0Oeqy6saZJNAaIgljDrxdePD75y/vhCSruigrwRvyCsUA/BFPQA@8xd8FPaL875rv4fyczPzDbUYr7wn@yp1qhp2YmM/Pr34AlY8iTcTh4KeYRxccp8zHPPY50o/JP@cRlfI45Xg8RvMoDKM/) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLNjpswEL7zFNM0Wmx@0jgr9QAhkXrtreqhVYgQcRywCgaBUbK72msfYB@xD9J07Ozmp1oj2Xjmm/m@GQ9v27Dg/PhRKl4NWwHzTdP0@lMnCnGYlG27cHiZd5C1qzUk8G30Zb//tbkffj48/Pheft6X5EiWCTkc/CVNmTem9ubTdOaP6cRbpl9ThqZ0thzTI/0/eBSA1yZZ67PYuSiQKKATeb1wUEsFfEN4o3oNVlkU1bnmZdaJfqh0Pz@5jEZvcQc1fer1Nop4M2iYz8HFD496UglV6JLQuBN66BTobhDxsyOVhjqXilB4cgBXu0JuBJOWhmydTGMYEHM/yzQ05mYCCvNjaRArVYHGdtCxjb9RapsIncBk8Zutt/JhX@avEbumA2LSPp7TFkJXUglyKkWq4MRA4zeVZpkQNcU3yXUjiQVMeIaKCKUBKBZA2/ToPnl2Um2JG7o0PidQDL0G8yG5riaKlDEu38kLvsX7wChESH7JZWfEM3RK7E@3lWI@W8dQi7oXmvQBuAfXCMNe9Og0zT3Hn5sgE2W6PE8Ui8H35XXFtuodkEcKKMqQEDdVWBK2jsU3sJshkGYbwZ/fL6Nb1PUzZUUnWsI3AZDLSIFH74zWUK7ftaO1E1ctfXYu@@ugYZHPRxay6ZT95bsqL/pjWFnizPL@Aw) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9BTsMwEEX3nGKIImwnjRVnibGsSmWFxAKxi6uoUDe1ZLmRk6ohiC0H4IhcJDgJ6nKe/pv5489vH6MHAS@61n1Dnb7AZv26pl7v9hyMyDlcjsZqsKLWXRvQAWyZsa0QkXIRD9yWOaVZseWg3X4GtG2s6TDKEFkEarWruyMmD0UIlMEO0iLcABxOHhwYBxOk3akymOWE0il4HedF5jYUas6hx3zKCMah8cZ14FYIfr9/AHEYhDOWA476KHGEtu87hz35XHJ4AIkA3SNEVvHdtRcfBPv6f2AqVVWPz5uqGrEUuO9TSRRLYjJPKVFFGhOaSPWkWECqkDEZR5axPGd/) - Ruby

This requires Perl/PCRE/Boost/Ruby due to the use of the `\K` (set start of match) function. Other than that, no features more advanced than those available in ECMAScript/Python are used.

```
(?=(xx+?)\1*$)   # \1 = smallest prime factor of tail
(?=(x+  )\2+$)   # \2 = largest proper divisor of tail
.*?\K\1(?=\2?$)  # Manipulate the match to be \1 exactly, using "\K" to start
                 # the match before it;
                 # if tail was prime, tail = 0, else tail = \2
```

Answer (score 1):

**Rockstar, 659 characters**

Not really my code, but quite fun, source quoted at bottom:

```
Depression takes your hope and your light
While your hope is as high as your light    
Put your hope without your light into your hope

If your hope is gone
Give back yes

Give back lies


Listen to your heart
My world is selflessness
Your faith is forgiveness
While your heart is bigger than your faith and depression taking your heart, my world
Whisper my world
Put your heart over my world into your heart

Build my world up
While your heart is bigger than your faith
While your heart is bigger than your faith and depression taking your heart, my world
Scream my world
Put your heart over my world into your heart

Build my world up, up
```

Source: https://github.com/RockstarLang/rockstar/blob/main/examples/factorization.rock

Rockstar language:
https://codewithrockstar.com/

Comment: Is all the white-space necessary?

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! :)

Comment: I don't think all the white space is necessary

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
f
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWYmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0yJTIwLSUzRSUyMDIlMkMlMEEzJTIwLSUzRSUyMDMlMkMlMEE0JTIwLSUzRSUyMDIlMkMlMjAyJTBBNiUyMC0lM0UlMjAyJTJDJTIwMyUwQTglMjAtJTNFJTIwMiUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAyJTBBMTIlMjAtJTNFJTIwMiUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAzJTBBMjU1JTIwLSUzRSUyMDMlMkMlMjA1JTJDJTIwMTclMEEyNTYlMjAtJTNFJTIwMiUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAyJTJDJTIwMiUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAyJTJDJTIwMiUyQyUyMDIlMEExMDAxJTIwLSUzRSUyMDclMkMlMjAxMSUyQyUyMDEzJmZsYWdzPUM=)

Built-in for "prime factors".

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
(ḅ}ÐRḣœḊhß÷
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSglRTElQjglODUlN0QlQzMlOTBSJUUxJUI4JUEzJUM1JTkzJUUxJUI4JThBaCVDMyU5RiVDMyVCNyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTYwJmZsYWdzPQ==)

No factor built-ins.

##### Explanation

```python
(ḅ}ÐRḣœḊhß÷  # Implicit input
(            # While loop:
 ḅ}          #   (condition)  not equal to 1
   Ð         #   (body)  triplicate the current number
    Rḣ       #           pop one copy and push [2..n]
      œḊh    #           first number it's divisible by
         ß   #           print this without popping
          ÷  #           and divide the number by this
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ForWhile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ForWhile), 30 bytes

`{1;[1+;[;;%!:[.';/;;1=!]):)..}`

Takes integer on stack as input, pushes prime factors on the stack

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=ezA7MSsoLjsxMCUiMCIuKzsyK34sMSsnMTAvJzspJy4oLCMpMTAjLn0wJCBcIHByaW50IHBvc2l0aXZlIGludAoKezE7WzErO1s7OyUhOlsuJzsvOzsxPSFdKTopLi59MSQKCgo0ICAgIDoyJDFAPzJAWzpbMEA_MV0pMTAjLiAgXCBjYWxsIGZ1bmN0aW9uIGFuZCBwcmludCBzdGFjawo1ICAgIDoyJDFAPzJAWzpbMEA_MV0pMTAjLgo2ICAgIDoyJDFAPzJAWzpbMEA_MV0pMTAjLgo3ICAgIDoyJDFAPzJAWzpbMEA_MV0pMTAjLgoyNTIwIDoyJDFAPzJAWzpbMEA_MV0pMTAjLg==)

### Explanation

````
{    }   \ anonymous procedure taking value n on stack as input
 1       \ push 1
  ;[     \ repeat n times
    1+   \ increase the counter by 1
      ;[ \ repeat up to n times
      
 ;;%!             \ check if n is divisible by the counter
     :[.        ] \ if yes
        ';/;;1=!  \ divide n by the counter and check if n is not equal to 1
   
   )     \ break the loop if the top stack value is zero
    :)   \ continue at the start of the loop
      .. \ cleanup stack
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>[77](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#XVBtbsIwDP2fUxitQy2UQBtoYaiMA@wIaCgr6ajUpqhJYRX0RLvFLsac8jVNSpQ8@9nv2ZUSsA9oPCckr6EbFxsB0fmY1xaPrPWcpmqwK9NcvL5a604n5zsYLFbJ8WQfLf6cnE62xYdR4nS7SUMpfe91IkicxrV9RNBbWNxpzth4qYXSEEGWSqFsh2KjFzhC/@ebxkX@YQ9Xm/7QgYaQJ9gUkGrgqpbxtixkUamsBl3AZ7oXoLciB55lwCHechkLkykradwvS6GqTCvUafUuKoMF2FYqd5V2e0vxtROxFhsHxZXmpcb3mjSjX4kOfUuVdu/sFkJzsYfrkPrio6g0HLZCGlQDLwV6l4JQxWtIihL4geMkN1u4YnL2jR@fMPMwMm6Ri4Hg@mNkeouZsOc/ECP@ZNLWuTBxwQsRB3/I/w7xRiPPpEPkenix3mejmT8NRzexttE9b3rinWExcr1xOJ6yYBw8yOxOZqZgYj7Me1DDlnpHvw)</s>  [64](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#XVBtboMwDP2fU1gaq6ClaSF8tKuoeoAdYdqUQRhIEBAJ3VDLiXaLXaxLoKXTpFjxs5/9XtIKBscAxzuEyg5mcZUwiC6nsjNoZLztSlrDcv@Sns7myaCP6flsGhSS/Bil1myW9hjjV0j3c6u3TVcBmO8NavUXtesgmZAQQZFzJkwLq1VPcILFzzeOq/LdXL0ki5UFPUIPkFSQS6Ci43HWVLxqRdGBrOAjPzKQGSuBFgVQiDPKY6Y7Tcu14UPDRFtIoXQGvVFluQfTyHndSnt@YF81iyVLLCUuJG2kuq9N/dor0cLPuZD2xB4g9KO9usm5HH1UrYTPjHGNOqANU945Q3j0gQXtIK2ayZf6VnRxtSEXEX0R5A3IVoXgmhG0udV02XHviCDX94c5G3wbnFDh4A/530HOeu3odqi4jgo175L11t2E65vYsGjq650qtmpYcR0v9DYk8II7mUxkogd8nRDnTg0H6oR@AQ) bytes

```perl6
{my$a=$_;.is-prime??$_!!map ->\f{|({$a%f||($a/=f)&&f}...^*!= f)},(2... *>$a)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#XVBtbsIwDP2fUxitQy2UQBtoYaiMA@wIaCgr6ajUpqhJYRX0RLvFLsac8jVNSpQ8@9nv2ZUSsA9oPCckr6EbFxsB0fmY1xaPrPWcpmqwK9NcvL5a604n5zsYLFbJ8WQfLf6cnE62xYdR4nS7SUMpfe91IkicxrV9RNBbWNxpzth4qYXSEEGWSqFsh2KjFzhC/@ebxkX@YQ9Xm/7QgYaQJ9gUkGrgqpbxtixkUamsBl3AZ7oXoLciB55lwCHechkLkykradwvS6GqTCvUafUuKoMF2FYqd5V2e0vxtROxFhsHxZXmpcb3mjSjX4kOfUuVdu/sFkJzsYfrkPrio6g0HLZCGlQDLwV6l4JQxWtIihL4geMkN1u4YnL2jR@fMPMwMm6Ri4Hg@mNkeouZsOc/ECP@ZNLWuTBxwQsRB3/I/w7xRiPPpEPkenix3mejmT8NRzexttE9b3rinWExcr1xOJ6yYBw8yOxOZqZgYj7Me1DDlnpHvw)

```perl6
{my$a=$_;map ->\f{|({$a%f||($a div=f)&&f}...^ f>*)},(2... *>$a)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#XVBtboMwDP2fU1gaq6ClaSF8tKuoeoAdYdqUQRhIEBAJ3VDLiXaLXaxLoKXTpFjxs5/9XtIKBscAxzuEyg5mcZUwiC6nsjNoZLztSlrDcv@Sns7myaCP6flsGhSS/Bil1myW9hjjV0j3c6u3TVcBmO8NavUXtesgmZAQQZFzJkwLq1VPcILFzzeOq/LdXL0ki5UFPUIPkFSQS6Ci43HWVLxqRdGBrOAjPzKQGSuBFgVQiDPKY6Y7Tcu14UPDRFtIoXQGvVFluQfTyHndSnt@YF81iyVLLCUuJG2kuq9N/dor0cLPuZD2xB4g9KO9usm5HH1UrYTPjHGNOqANU945Q3j0gQXtIK2ayZf6VnRxtSEXEX0R5A3IVoXgmhG0udV02XHviCDX94c5G3wbnFDh4A/530HOeu3odqi4jgo175L11t2E65vYsGjq650qtmpYcR0v9DYk8II7mUxkogd8nRDnTg0H6oR@AQ) ( Note: it doesn't have enough time allotted to finish )

---

A much more performant version is slightly longer at 100 bytes.

```perl6
{my$a=$_;map ->\f{|({$a.is-prime??($/=$a)&&($a=0)||$/!!($a%f||($a div=f)&&f)}...^ f>*)},(2... *>$a)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#XVDhToMwEP7fpzgjLjBZB3SDqWHuAXwEo6lQHAmUhZYpGTyRb@GLzSubzJi0ufvuvuv39RolYB/S5IGQsoVJUqUC4uOhbC0eW68PJd/BbP2cHTr7YHGaq9muzkvx@Ghb89jizmRiI9Fzus6aX11hfpN1HQZI832cYTtzekrpC2TrqdO7doAApmuc7I@ot9FCaYihyKVQtkNR7h4OcPv9RZOqfLPnz@nt3IGekGtIK8g1cNXKZFtXsmpU0YKu4D3fC9BbUQIvCuCQbLlMhOnUjTSf2tRCNYVWqDPonVRma7CtXO4a7U434nMnEi1SB8WV5rXGeG6ajZyJDn3KlXZH9gChP9nDvUh98lE1Gj62QhrUAq8FepeC0JMPqngLWVWPvnD15BgYQwFhJjCyGJCLhfCcMbL6rZmyH1wQI8FyOcy5sHTBjxCHf8j/DvE9zzftCLk@XpwPmHcXrCLvV2x4aOybN/He4TBy/UW0WLFwEV7IbCQzM7A0CfMv1GigjugH)

---

### Expanded: <sup><sub>(64 byte version)</sub></sup>

```perl6
{
  my $a = $_;  # the input ｢$_｣ is read-only by default
  map
    -> \f {
      |(              # slip ( flattens into outer list )

        # generate sequence of 0 or more ｢f｣s
        {
          $a % f      # is it not evenly divisible

          ||          # if it is evenly divisible
          ($a div=f)  # divide it
          &&          # and
          f           # return ｢f｣
        }
        ...^   # keep doing that until
        f > *  # ｢f｣ is bigger
      )

    },

    # do that over the following list

    (2 ... * > $a) # generate a sequence from 2
                   # up to whatever the value of $a
                   # is at the time of the check
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### VB.NET, 86 bytes

Had this sitting around from some Project Euler programs. Removed the optimizations in the interest of shortness, and this is the result.  Naturally, VB is very verbose, so it's fairly long. I'm not counting the leading whitespace. It can be omitted, but is easier to read with it.

This takes an integer as a parameter, and prints the prime factors with a comma after. There is a trailing comma at the end.

```
Sub A(a)
    For i=2To a ' VB re-evaluates a each time, so the /= at the end of the loop shortens this
        While a Mod i=0 ' this is a factor. We've grabbed primes before this, so this must be a prime factor
            Console.Write(i &",") ' output
            a/=i ' "mark" the prime as "used"
        End While
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 51 bytes

A recursive solution:

```
sub f(\n,\d=2){n-1??n%d??f n,d+1!!(d,|f n/d,d)!!()}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 61 bytes

```
require'prime';->x{x.prime_division.flat_map{|x|[x[0]]*x[1]}}
```

Shortest builtin-version I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
n=input();i=1
while~-n:
 i+=1
 while n%i<1:print i;n/=i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERD0zrT1pCrPCMzJ7VON8@KSyFTG8hXAAso5Klm2hhaFRRl5pUoZFrn6dtm/v9vZGhibmJhbGZiBgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 83 bytes

```scala
def f(n:Int,k:Int=2):Seq[Int]=if(n<k)Seq();else if(n%k==0)k+:f(n/k,k);else f(n,k+1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sODkxJ9F4wc78pKzU5BIF38TMPIXUipLUvJRiBceCAoXqpaUlaboWN4NTUtMU0jTyrDzzSnSyQaStkaZVcGphNJAZa5sJlLLJ1gTyNTStU3OKUxVAIqrZtrYGmtnaVkC2frZONlQKyNPJ1jbUhBi9hUtBoaAoM68kJ08jTcPI1FRTk6sWIrVgAYQGAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 10.5  bytes (21 nibbles)

```
!;`.$/$=2|,$~%@$>>@/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWWxStE_RU9FVsjWp0VOpUHVTs7Bz0IVJQFeuilYwMTcxNLIzNTMyUYqGiAA)

```
  `.                        # iterate while unique 
    $                       # starting with input:
     /$                     #   itself divided by
       =2|,$~%@$            #   its first divisor;
 ;                          # now, remember this list
!                           # and zip it with
                  >>@       # itself without its first element
                     /      # by division
```