# Find the nth Aaron number

Tags: code-golf, sequence

## Background

A [Ruth-Aaron pair](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ruth-AaronPair.html) is a pair of consecutive positive integers `n` and `n+1` such that the sum of the prime factors (counting repeated prime factors) of each integer are equal. For example, `(714,715)` is a Ruth-Aaron pair, since `714=2*3*7*17`, `715=5*11*13`, and `2+3+7+17=5+11+13=29`. The name Ruth-Aaron pair was chosen by [Carl Pomerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Pomerance) in reference to [Babe Ruth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babe_Ruth)'s career home run total of `714`, which stood as the world record from May 25, 1935 until April 8, 1974 when [Hank Aaron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hank_Aaron) hit his `715`th home run. You can learn more about the fascinating history of these numbers in this [Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCq04N9it8U).

## Goal

Write a complete program or function which, given a positive integer `n`, outputs the `n`th Aaron number, where the `n`th number is defined to be the larger integer of the `n`th Ruth-Aaron pair. Thus the `n`th Aaron number is `a(n)+1`, where `a(n)` is the `n`th term in the OEIS sequence [A039752](https://oeis.org/A039752).

## Test cases

The first few Aaron numbers are

```
6,9,16,78,126,715,949,1331,1521,1863,2492,3249,4186,4192,5406,5561,5960,6868,8281,8464,10648,12352,14588,16933,17081,18491,20451,24896,26643,26650,28449,28810,33020,37829,37882,41262,42625,43216
```

## Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- [Input and output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) may be in any convenient format.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

Comment: To be sure, "counting multiplicity" means that 20 -> 2, 2, 5 not 2, 5 right?

Comment: @Okx I was, I just noticed that when I refreshed his Youtube profile, he had exactly 1 more subscriber (not me)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yes. I'll edit to make more clear.

Comment: Can we choose between 0 and 1 indexing?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yes you may

Comment: I too, watched today's Numberphile video

Comment: [I predicted this...](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39272297#392722970)

Comment: @Okx You mean you predicted [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39272297#39272297)?

Comment: Just curious for 1 byte: Can I use 2 indexing?

Comment: @Titus I think that's fine

Comment: Oh wait ... it´s 3-indexed and saves <s>3</s> 2 bytes :D nm; that´s penny picking. I´ll go with 1-indexed.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Emigna
-1 byte thanks to Adnan

```
µN>Ð<‚ÒOË
```

Explanation:

```
µ            While the counter variable (which starts at 0) is not equal to the input:
 N>          Store the current iteration index + 1, and then create an array with
   Ð<‚       [current iteration index + 1, current iteration index]
      ÒO     Get the sum of the prime factors of each element
        Ë    If all elements in the array are equal,
             implicitly increment the counter variable
```

1-indexed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0FY/u8MTbB41zDo8yf9w9///ZgA)

Comment: Explanation when you can, please :)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Added.

Comment: 10 bytes: `µN>Ð<‚ÒOË½`

Comment: @Emigna Ah, nice one.

Comment: You can leave out the `½` as this will be auto-appended when missing in the `µ`-loop body

Comment: @Adhnan Really? That's a crazy language feature.

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to a clever golf by @Leo

```
€∫Ẋ¤=oΣpN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9odXNr///igqziiKvhuorCpD1vzqNwTv///zY)

#### Explanation

```
  Ẋ     N   -- map function over all consecutive pairs ... of natural numbers           [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)...]
   ¤=       --   are the results of the following function equal for both in the pair?
     oΣp    --     sum of prime factors                                                   [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
 ∫          -- cumulative sum                                                           [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]                
€           -- the index of the first value equal to the input
```

Comment: Nice work, I was about to post substantially the same idea :)

Comment: A golfier version https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9odXNr///igqziiKvhuorCpD1vzqNwTv///zY

Comment: @Leo Ooh, `€∫` is a really nice trick! And one that only works in a lazy language. ;)

Comment: @Leo Very clever.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
;‘ÆfS€Eµ⁸#Ṫ‘
```

A monadic link taking and returning non-negative numbers

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/6UcOMw21pwY@a1rge2vqocYfyw52rgGL///83AwA)**

#### How?

```
;‘ÆfS€Eµ⁸#Ṫ‘ - Link: number, n
         #   - n-find (counting up, say with i, from implicit 1)
        ⁸    - ...number of matches to find: chain's left argument, n
       µ     - ...action: the monadic chain with argument i:
 ‘           -   increment = i+1
;            -   concatenate = [i,i+1]
  Æf         -   prime factors (with duplicates, vectorises)
    S€       -   sum €ach
      E      -   all (two of them) equal?
          Ṫ  - tail, the last matching (hence nth) i
           ‘ - increment (need to return i+1)
```

Comment: Save a byte with [`;’ÆfS€E_Ịµ#`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/6UcPMw21pwY@a1rjGP9zddWir8v///w0B).

Comment: Still need the tail.

Comment: And that's what you get for testing only with `1`.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 17 bytes

```
`@:"@Yfs]vd~sG<}@
```

1-based. Very slow.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8HBSskhMq04tiylrtjdptbh/39TAA)

#### Explanation

```
`        % Do...while
  @      %   Push iteration index k, starting at 1
  :      %   Range [1 2 ... k]
  "      %   For each j in [1 2 ... k]
    @    %     Push j
    Yf   %     Row vector of prime factors
    s    %     Sum
  ]      %   End
  v      %   Concatenate whole stack into a column vector
  d      %   Consecutive differences. A zero indicates a Ruth-Aaron pair
  ~s     %   Number of zeros
  G<     %   Is it less than the input? If so: next k. Else: exit loop
}        % Finally (execute right before when the loop is exited)
  @      %   Push current k
         % Implicit end. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), <s>23</s> 20 bytes

This is 1-indexed.

```
WhQ=-QqsPZsPhZ=+Z1;Z
```

**[Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=WhQ%3D-QqsPZsPhZ%3D%2BZ1%3BZ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9&debug=0)** or **[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=WhQ%3D-QqsPZsPhZ%3D%2BZ1%3BZ&input=6&debug=0)**

---

## Explanation

```
WhQ=-QqsPZsPhZ=+Z1;Z  - Full program. Takes input from Standard input.

WhQ                      - While Q is still higher than 0.
       sPZ               - Sum of the prime factors of Z.
          sPhZ           - Sum of the prime factors of Z+1.
      q                  - If the above are equal:
   =-Q                     - Decrement Q by 1 if they are equal, and by 0 if they are not.
              =+Z1;      - Increment Z on each iteration.
                   Z     - Output Z.
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>93 92</s> 91+1 bytes

```php
while(2+$argn-=$a==$b)for($b=$a,$a=!$x=$n+=$k=1;$k++<$x;)for(;$x%$k<1;$x/=$k)$a+=$k;echo$n;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3748c7b7f83fe2109c1f8115f01d8b35fa70e2d8).

-2 bytes with 3-indexed (fist Aaron number for argument `3`): remove `2+`.

**breakdown**

```php
while(2+$argn       # loop until argument reaches -2 (0 and 1 are false positives)
    -=$a==$b)           # 0. if factors sum equals previous, decrement argument
    for($b=$a,          # 1. remember factors sum
        $a=!            # 3. reset factors sum $a
        $x=$n+=         # 2. pre-increment $n and copy to $x
        $k=1;$k++<$x;)  # 4. loop $k from 2 to $x
        for(;$x%$k<1;       # while $k divides $x
            $x/=$k)             # 2. and divide $x by $k
            $a+=$k;             # 1. add $k to factors sum
echo$n;             # print Aaron number $n
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 97 bytes

```
(t=r=1;While[t<=#,If[SameQ@@(Plus@@((#&@@# #[[2]])&/@FactorInteger@#)&/@{#,#+1}&@r),t++];r++];r)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfo8S2yNbQOjwjMyc1usTGVlnHMy06ODE3NdDBQSMgp7QYSGkoqzk4KCsoR0cbxcZqquk7uCUml@QXeeaVpKanFjkog4SqlXWUtQ1r1RyKNHVKtLVjrYvAhKba/4CizLwSBYe0aNPY/wA)

Comment: It needs to output the larger of the pair according to the description; `6` returns `714` instead of `715`, for example.

Comment: @numbermaniac fixed! saved 2 bytes!

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <strike>12</strike> 11 bytes

```
e.fqsPtZsPZ
```

Indexing from 1 removes a byte, and puts Pyth ahead of Jelly

---

## Explanation

```
e.fqsPtZsPZ  - Full program. Takes input from Standard input.

e.f          - Last element of the list of the first $input numbers for which
   q         - Are equal 
    s   s    - The sum of
     PtZ PZ  - Prime factors of $number-1 and $number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
ÆfS=’ÆfS$$µ³‘¤#ṖṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW1qw7aOGmSBaReXQ1kObHzXMOLRE@eHOaQ93rvr//78hAA)

## Explanation

```
ÆfS=’ÆfS$$µ³‘¤#ṖṪ  Main link, argument is z
              #    Find the first       elements that satisfy condition y: <y><z>#
           ³‘¤                    z + 1
          µ        Monadic link, where the condition is:
  S                The sum of
Æf                            the array of primes that multiply to the number
   =               equals
       S           The sum of
     Æf                       the prime factors of
    ’                                              the number before it
        $$         Last two links as a monad, twice
               Ṗ   k -> k[:-1]
                Ṫ  Last element (combined with `pop`, gets the second last element)
```

1-indexed

Comment: I am not sure 2-indexing is allowed by default rules.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Sure, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>89</s> 86 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1..1/s=0.0).find{|x|r,c=2,0
0while x%r<1?(x/=r;c+=r):x>=r+=1
(c==s)?0>n-=1:!s=c}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FczdCoIwFADg@/MUdhFsqHOzH8E680HEi1qOhBqyEZ3QPfvC7wE@/7n/ksVUarcwJYSqAkohubCTeywrrb4wWBcS5Pc5vcaM9v6qOkYV@ovJ0fOWNPocFTCDGHgntStRtbuAJsa0lQ0X79u8XXPWU2F7GoaYFNRwgCOc4AzNHw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 19 bytes

```
1+_°k x ¥Zk x «U´}a
```

Uses 1-indexing.

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=MStfsGsgeCClWmsgeCCrVbR9YQ==&input=MTA=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>119 104 102</s> 101 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=2:n/k and(f(n,k+1),k+f(n/k))[n%k<1]
i=input();g=0
while-~i:i-=f(g)==f(g+1);g+=1
print(g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU7NDoIwGLt/T7GL2RYkuPmXgN9beDMeJoyxDD8IgagXX32OeGnapk07fuZuIB3robHIOY8t9ub5aAyjbUBdUhGYoUa0IulMyQSJFkHKG23CRd3Bo6dxmYWsHO7g1fne5l9f@hxb4SSumHqVy1DBOHmakxvT0j/KrtNiS2DMvm3N1hdRgYY9HOAIJzj/AA)

**-17 bytes** thanks to @ovs!

**-1 byte** thanks to @notjagan

Credit goes to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104591/59487) for the prime factorization algorithm. 1-indexed.

---

> **Note:** This is extremely slow and inefficient. Inputs higher than 7 will crash unless you set `import sys` and do `sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)`, but it works in theory.

Comment: [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##LU7BDoIwFLu/r9jFbAsYHIom4PsLb8YDwhgvwwchEPXr50i8NG3Tpp2@Sz9yHpqxtSilDB0O9evZ1oJTj3nJmRc1t6pTUSdGR4g086nX@s47fzUPICSe1kXpyuEB3j0NVlBiStpjp5zGDWO1cgkamGbiJbohjv2zt3m1JQhhP7YR25FgIIcjnKCAM1x@) by making `f` a function calculating the sum of prime factors

Comment: Would be great if you would track your bytecount (and maybe comment your edits).

Comment: `(f(n,k+1),k+f(n/k))[n%k<1]` for another -2 bytes. This makes it even slower.

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##JU7NDoIwGLt/T7GL2RYkuPmXgN9beDMeJoyxDD8IgagXX32OeGnapk07fuZuIB3robHIOY8t9ub5aAyjbUBdUhGYoUa0IulMyQSJFkHKG23CRd3Bo6dxmYWsHO7g1fne5l9f@hxb4SSumHqVy1DBOHmakxvT0j/KrtNiS2DMvm3N1hdRgYY9HOAIJzj/AA) by switching `i+1` to `-~i`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Èk x ¶Yk x}iU1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yGsgeCC2WWsgeH1pVTE&input=Ng)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 13 bytes

```
⟨:)ḍΣ¤ḍΣ=⟩#e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//9H8FVaaD3f0nlt8aAmYsn00f6Vyqub//0YA)