# Prime Factorization

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, primes, factoring

Although there was a prime factors challenge posted [ten years ago](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1979/find-the-prime-factors), it has tedious I/O and restricted time. In this challenge, your task is to write a program or function which takes an integer \$n \ge 2\$ as input, and returns its prime factors.

**Task:**

Input will consist of an integer, \$n \ge 2\$. Your program should theoretically work for arbitrarily large numbers, but can fail due to limits like integer overflow.

Your program should print/return the prime factors (in any order), in any reasonable representation. For example, `180` could be represented as `[2, 2, 3, 3, 5]`, or `"2 3 5 2 3"`, or through any other collection type or string representation.

**Test cases:**

```
2       [2]
3       [3]
6       [2, 3]
12      [2, 2, 3]
25      [5, 5]
180     [2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
181     [181]
```

**Other:**

Any trivial built-in answers should go in [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226551/79857) community wiki.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer (in bytes) per language wins.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, 43 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i=2)=>n%i?n-1?f(n,i+1):"":i+" "+f(n/i)
```

Outputs a space separated list with a trailing space.  It dies pretty quickly due to recursion limits, partially because it restarts at 2 every time it finds a new prime.

Answer (score 1):

## Trivial Answers (Community Wiki)

**Edit**: This challenge is closed. Please do not add solutions here; instead, consider creating a CW for trivial solutions on the dupe target, or just post your answer there as there are already many trivial solutions.

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
ǐ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C7%90&inputs=180&header=&footer=)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Æf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9r///@NDQA)

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.factors`, 7 bytes

```
factors
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVdQlJmbWqyXBpYpVihOLSxNzUtOLVYoKEotKakESueVKFhzcVVzKQCBEZg0BpNmYNIQImRkCuFZGEBpQ65ahej/UGP/xwItK1AoLklMztb7DwA)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
Ò
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8KT//w0tDAA)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 2 bytes

```
q:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/C63@a3KlJmfkK6QpGFoY/AcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
ʀǎ:£$vǑ¥Zƛ÷w$ẋ;f
```

[Try it Online at your own risk!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CA%80%C7%8E%3A%C2%A3%24v%C7%91%C2%A5Z%C6%9B%C3%B7w%24%E1%BA%8B%3Bf&inputs=180&header=&footer=)

It is horrendously slow for large numbers, but it works

### Explained

```
ʀǎ:£$vǑ¥Zƛ÷w$ẋ;f
ʀǎ                  # nth prime for each item in the range [0 ... input - 1]
  :£                # put that into the register while leaving it on the stack
    $vǑ             # get the divisbilty of each prime into the input
       ¥Z           # and zip that with the register
        ƛ     ;     # for each item in that zipped list: (each item is: [divisbilty, prime factor])
         ÷w         #      push divisbilty, [prime_factor]
           $ẋ       #      and repeat [prime_factor] divisibility times
               f    # flatten the unholy mess that results from doing the above
```

Answer (score 0):

**Matlab**, **17 bytes**

```
factor(input(''))
```