# Find all problems that equal an integer

Tags: code-challenge, number

In this challenge, your job is to write a program that allows a user to enter an integer. Then, the program must find all the possible ways of multiplying two numbers to get the user's integer.

**Rules:**

- The program should not show any problem more than once.
- The user should be able to enter any integer.
- The program should only show problems that contain 2 numbers.
- The shortest program (in Bytes) wins.
- It does not matter what order the program outputs the problems in.

**Example Output (user enters 20, then the program outputs the problems):**

> > 20
> >
> > 1 * 20
> >     2 * 10
> >     4 * 5

Comment: So basically this is just "factor an integer." *predicts ridiculously short Mathematica solution*

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow yes but all possible factorizations.

Comment: What do you mean "yes, but all possible factorizations"? That's what factoring is. Unless you mean including non-integer "factors", in which case there are _infinite_ solutions.

Comment: This is just factoring, which has been done before: [Factorize me!!!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1979/factorize-me), [Find prime factors](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/667/194)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Perl 6, <s>54</s> <s>52</s> 49 characters

```
my \i=get;i%$_||say $_,"*",i/$_ for 1...^*>i.sqrt
```

Iterates through each integer from 1 to the first number greater than the square root of the input (`* > i.sqrt`), excludes that last number (`...^`), and prints (`say $_,"*",i/$_`) unless the number doesn't divide the input evenly (`i % $_ ||`)

Answer (score 3):

Let's give **VIM** some love (96 chars)

```
let n=input('')|for x in range(1,n/2-1)|for y in range(1,n)|if x*y==n|ec x."*".y|en|endfo|endfo
```

The abbreviations `ec`, `en` and `endfo` stand for `echo`, `endif` and `endfor` respectively.

I was rather disappointed that I couldn't use `fo`; that expands to `fold`.

Answer (score 1):

### python, <s>85</s> <s>79</s> <s>75</s> 73 characters

```
i,j=1,int(raw_input())
while i*i<=j:
    if j%i==0:
        print i,"*",j/i
    i+=1
```

This can probably be improved drastically...

Comment: Pretty good (for Python!)

Comment: Design for readability really kills in codegolf, but I bet Java can't beat that :P

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 64 characters

Algorithm: run for loop till square root of the input number and if `n % i == 0` alert the pair of numbers.

```
n=prompt();for(i=1;i<Math.sqrt(n);i++)if(!(n%i))alert(i+"*"+n/i)
```

Answer (score 0):

### C, <strike>75</strike> <strike>71</strike> 70 characters

```
n;main(i){scanf("%d",&n);for(;i*i<n;i++)n%i||printf("%d*%d\n",i,n/i);}
```

Relies on the fact that the program is called with 0 arguments so `i` is initialized to `1`.  I am currently beating the python solution, so I am quite estatic. :D

Answer (score 0):

### perl 5 82 characters...

```
  my $n=20;
  for(1..sqrt($n)){
    say "$_ * ",$n/$_ if $n%$_ == 0;
  }
```