# ROT13 one ASCII character

Tags: code-golf, printable-ascii

[This kind of question has been asked before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4/rot-13-transform-standard-input), but I wanted to make it more specific. The linked question asks to read from stdin and rot13 the input. I don't want the disadvantage of I/O code that differs a lot for each language in length.

The challenge:

> Write a function that will [ROT13 (wiki link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) one char (as defined by the ASCII table).
>   **No built-in ROT13 functionality allowed.**

Shortest code wins.

---

You can use this kind of C-family loop to test your function:

```
for (int i = '!'; i <= '~'; ++i)
{
    char c = (char) i;
    System.out.println(c + "   ->   " + f(c));
}
```

Comment: @Howard: I linked that question myself. But that is different. Here the task is to rotate only one char.

Comment: The difference is minor only - almost all answers from the other question can be user with litte modifications.

Comment: @Howard: The most important difference is that I don't want the I/O code here. Just the plain algorithm.

Comment: In my opinion changing I/O doesn't justify a new question in this case.

Answer (score 3):

**C (<del>77</del> 64 chars)**

<del>`char f(char c){return(c>64&&c<91)?65+(c-52)%26:(c>96&&c<123)?97+(c-84)%26:c;}`</del>

```
char f(char c){return(isalpha(c))?65+(c&32)+(c-52-(c&32))%26:c;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this in **Java (81 chars)**:

```
char f(char c){return Character.isLetter(c)?(char)((((c&95)-52)%26+65)|c&32):c;}
```

Demo here: http://ideone.com/ItT7IM