# ROT13 and upside-down text (flip text)

Tags: code-golf

When I saw this title in the Hot Network Questions I thought it was going to be a PPCG challenge. I was a little disappointed when it was on [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147829/rot13-and-upside-down-text-flip-text).

So now it is on PPCG:

### Challenge

Given an input string, output the [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13), flipped value. The input will contain characters from the following alphabet: `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz <flipped alphabet>]`<sup>1</sup>

The flipped alphabet can be anything visually similar to the flipped lowercase Latin alphabet so long as it can be accepted as input.

The space character should remain unchanged.

As an example, your flipped alphabet might be `zʎxʍʌnʇsɹbdouɯlʞɾᴉɥƃɟǝpɔqɐ`

### Example

```
Input:    caesar woz ere
Rot13:    pnrfne jbm rer
Output:   ɹǝɹ ɯqɾ ǝuɟɹud

Input:    ɹǝɹ ɯqɾ ǝuɟɹud
Rot13:    pnrfne jbm rer
Output:   caesar woz ere
```

### Scoring

Simple [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the lowest number of bytes wins.

---

I think this is different enough to the [proposed duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/125214/edit) for a few reasons:

- The answerer has the choice of which characters to use as output (within limits)
- The process should be reversible. i.e. flipped text should be acceptable as input and return "normal" text.
- There is the opportunity for graphical solutions in this question.

Comment: Please include a list of the flipped alphabet.

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4/48934)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer, I think it's probably different enough for a few reasons. I've added my reasons to the question.

Comment: @JamesWebster Then, first of all, what are the limits? Second, what do you mean by "graphical solutions"? If the output is an image, are the solutions below supposed to take that image as input and print the original text or something?

Comment: The limit is mentioned in the question: `The flipped alphabet can be anything visually similar to the flipped lowercase Latin alphabet so long as it can be accepted as input`. I've clarified the `output as input` section, however. By graphical solution, I understand that Mathemetica would be to rotate text rather than replace characters.

Comment: `There is the opportunity for graphical solutions in this question.`: I don't see how unless you are performing some OCR.

Comment: Your flipped alphabet contains letters from the roman alphabet, so it's impossible to know whether `d` is a flipped `p` and should therefore rot13 to `ɔ` before flipping to `c`, rather than rot13 to `q` and flipping to `b`.

Comment: Your upside-down `q` is a `b`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 120 bytes

*many bytes saved thanks to @JonathanAllan*

```python
lambda s,a='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz VOďƄɹ5ʇη^MXʎ2ɐʠ>Pəɟ6ɥ!ɾʞ|W ':''.join(a[(a.find(c)+27)%54]for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFYJ9FWPTEpOSU1LT0jMys7Jzcvv6CwqLiktKy8orJKIcz/SP@xlpM7TU@1n9se5xtxqs/o5IRTC@wCTs48Od/s5FLFk/tOzasJV1C3UlfXy8rPzNNIjNZI1EvLzEvRSNbUNjLXVDU1iU3LL1JIVsjMUyjW/F9QlJlXopGmoZScmFqcWKRQnl@lkFqUqqSpyQWXOtIfdnLnyflhJ2cqAM1fEK4A5M08uROo5j8A)

Comment: @JonathanAllan fixed (plus space issue). in case of ambiguity (like `"uodb"`) will choose the normal alphabet to translate *from*

Comment: Nice fix, although the `[abc... <flipped>]` does suggest one alphabet and possible mixed input, maybe you can save bytes and fix both at the same time by picking some other unicode chars?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I already tested the option to use a single string (with `a[(a.index(x)+27)%54]`, but I didn't find decent replacements for the overlapping characters.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I can't see dennis' tio links (wifi provider blocks)

Comment: Wow, why? OK `lambda s,a='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz υοďƄɹ5ʇηʌʍXʎ2ɐʠɔǷəɟɓɥ!ɾʞ|ɯ ':''.join(a[(a.find(c)+27)%54]for c in s)`

Comment: @JonathanAllan wish I knew. nice use for `Ƅ` `Ƿ` and `|`. I think the last one can use the integral sign, and `ᴉ` does not need to be replaced by `!`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60161/discussion-between-jonathan-allan-and-uriel).

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 234 bytes

```
T=ToExpression;B=Characters;L=T@CharacterRange["a","z"];K=T@B@"uodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎzɐqɔpǝɟƃɥᴉɾʞlɯ";(If[Max@ToCharacterCode@#<123,A=L;F=K,A=K;F=L];S=Association@Table[ToRules[A[[Z]]==F[[Z]]],{Z,Length@L}];Row@Reverse@T@B@#/.S)&
```